# My prefix is food, my suffix is rude

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

I thought of this riddle myself. Feedback is appreciated.

> My prefix is food.
>
> My suffix is rude.
>
> My infix comes in rounds.
>
> I keep you off the ground.

What am I?

Comment: Great riddle, not much room for mis-interpretation really. Very concise!

Comment: Definitely one of the better riddles in a while! Nice, common(ish) word for answer, almost certainly an unique answer, clearly worded clues, which are also fun wordplays. Well, basically what Paige said already :-) Very well done indeed!

Comment: Great riddle! Also, thanks for teaching me "infix"

Comment: @Riley You definitely started a trend. Fabulous and creative . This kinda reminds me of rebuses, except you use words for it.

Comment: @North, so there are riley rebus now! :)

Answer (score 205, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is

> Hammock

My prefix is food.

> Ham

My suffix is rude.

> Mock

My infix comes in rounds.

> Rounds of ammo

I keep you off the ground.

> That's usually the goal :)

Comment: Equally great answer!

Comment: I couldn't figure out the infix, but now that I see it, it all makes sense!

Comment: Yup, that's the answer.

Answer (score 80):

I know the riddle was already answered, but I was thinking of another possible answer:

(Warning, the spoiler tag also contains an obscenity, if you're very sensitive to that sort of thing.)

> The esoteric programming language [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck).

My prefix is food.

> I'm pretty sure I've heard of cooked animal brains being served as food, either as part of some cuisine, or as exotic food.

My suffix is rude.

> The classic four-letter word.

My infix comes in rounds.

> "inf" is the mathematical abbreviation of "infimum", which could be used within a mathematical definition of the "rounding" operation (more specifically, in defining either the floor or the ceiling function).

I keep you off the ground.

> Being an esoteric programming language, no "grounded" programmer would want to use it for practical problems.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calf%27s_brains

Comment: Weird name for a programming language

Answer (score 74):

> [Diplodocus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplodocus)

My prefix is food.

> Dip is a type of appetizer, e.g., bean dip

My suffix is rude.

> Cus, short for cuss

My infix comes in rounds.

> A doc, or doctor, comes in while doing their rounds

I keep you off the ground.

> All you need is a diplodocus saddle!

Comment: You got a definite plus 1 for "All you need is a <spoiler> saddle".

Comment: This is the most creative answer. I love it.

Answer (score 56):

Perhaps this isn’t a good answer, but I couldn’t help not to include it. The clues weren’t taken literally to describe the parts of the answer, but instead the process:

Answer:

> A fart

My prefix is food.

> Starts as food that gets broken down by bacteria

My suffix is rude.

> When it comes out the rear, it’s considered rude

My infix comes in rounds.

> Like intestines

I keep you off the ground.

> As gas does

Comment: Wait this is an amazing answer...

Comment: Smart thoughts. I appreciate this one

Comment: off the ground: from whence we get the expression "hoist by one's own petard"

Answer (score 20):

With a slightly generous definition of prefix, suffix and infix. (Spoiler tags hide rude language)

Answer:

> Cock

My prefix is food.

> Cock (slang for chicken)

My suffix is rude.

> Cock (is rude)

My infix comes in rounds.

> Cock (most men need some time to, uh, recharge before they come again.)

I keep you off the ground.

> In bed is off the ground.

Comment: Slightly too risque, but it makes sense...

Comment: @NL628 just looked at [your Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63790/another-riley-riddle). Really nice :D

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it's

> Flatulence.   Food precedes flatulence, releasing it near others may be considered rude, the smell alone may be quite offensive, it comes in rounds until eventually you have to go to the bathroom and it keeps you off the ground because the conventional western toilet, you'll sit 14 or 15 inches above the floor, which is where you'll be after a few flatulence cycles.

Comment: Hi, welcome to puzzling.SE! It seems your answer is the same as @vol7ron's.

Answer (score 4):

An answer to this is

> **crude**

My prefix is food.

> **crud**: Another way of spelling curd, the coagulated of **milk**.

My suffix is rude.

> **rude**: Speaks for itself.

My infix comes in rounds.

> **rud**: The color of a person's skin, especially the face. Faces are **round**.

I keep you off the ground.

> **crude**: Crude oil comes from underground. If the crude oil reaches ground level, who wouldn't want to get their feet **off the ground**?

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer:

> Applause?

> My prefix is food

> App == food,

> My suffix is rude

> Use is rude (in the sense of taking advantage of someone),

> My infix comes in rounds

> "la" comes in rounds (as in musical rounds...fa la la la la...)

> I keep you off the ground

> And what keeps someone in the clouds like a good bit of applause?

Comment: How is App == food?

Comment: @CaptainLepton Appetizer?

Comment: @noedne Seems rather tenuous