# I start with an animal and finish with a material

Tags: riddle

> I start with an animal,
>
> And finish with a material,
>
> I also entertain people,
>
> And make your house beautiful.

As most answers already have this, hint 1 is:

> Wood

*Got the idea based on [this great riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude).*

Comment: I am new here, so I don't know the correct way, as @Randal'Thor said, it's the form of the riddle thats based on, no other correlation...

Comment: When I saw the title, I immediately thought of Fishsticks. The stick part even matched the hint! And then I read the rest of the riddle...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Tiger Woods. Tigerwood makes your house lovely. Tiger Woods entertains people with his golf.

Comment: Finally someone got it :)

Comment: Interesting that xyz is considered an entertainer though. Took me a while to see xyz like that.

Comment: I used entertainer too make it harder :P

Answer (score 5):

How about

> dogwood?

Starts with an animal:

> dog.

Ends with a material:

> wood.

Entertain people:

> according to Wikipedia, dogwood is used to make mountain dulcimers, a type of musical instrument.

Make your house beautiful:

> maybe dogwood is used in some kind of interior decoration?

(I posted this answer after seeing Herb Wolfe's, but *thought* of it before. At first I'd thought it unlikely, but given the OP's comment that Herb was close, maybe it's worth a try after all.)

Comment: Real Close as well!

Comment: dang, I changed mine, as I thought this was it. Must put my thinking cap back on.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> <strike>Basswood?</strike> Dogwood

Starts with an animal:

> <strike>Bass - a type of fish</strike> Dog, a pet, and man's best friend.

Finishes with a material:

> Wood, obviously a material.

Entertains people:

> <strike>Many guitars are made using basswood, and guitars entertain people.</strike>
>  According to this Wikipedia [disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogwood_%28disambiguation%29), dogwood can refer to, among other things, a thoroughbred race, a NASCAR race, an amateur golf tournament, or a Christian punk band, any of which can be entertaining to people.

Makes your house beautiful:

> <strike>The basswood tree can be used as an ornamental tree, which would make your house beautiful, and the wood itself is used for furniture and other decorative household items.</strike>
>  The dogwood tree is also an ornamental tree, and the beautiful wood can be used for a variety of smaller objects requiring a hard wood.

Comment: Almost correct, Real close!! :)

Comment: lol @Bass: ^^ above answer = BassWood. Nice one

Answer (score 3):

New guess. Are you...

> Wormwood? Starts with "worm" (sort of an animal), ends with "wood", is [an entertaining series on Netflix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormwood_(miniseries)), and can be [an ornamental plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemisia_absinthium) for your house.

Old guess was...

> A dogwood tree. Starts with "dog", ends with "wood", and makes your house beautiful. Not sure about the entertainment part, though.

Comment: Also as @Herb, real close!

Comment: Oops, looks like we jinxed each other!

Comment: @GustavoGabriel: Is my newer guess any closer?

Comment: Nope, I would say the animal is farther :P

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are

> pigskin.

Starts with an animal

> pig

Finishes with a material

> skin

I also entertain people

> football is entertaining to many people

And make your house beautiful

> Furniture made of pigskin (leather)

Comment: Unfortunately not correct, the other answers are a little closer as well

Answer (score 2):

How about

> Houndstooth

I start with an animal

> "Hound" is another word for Dog, which is an animal

And finish with a material

> Teeth are made from dentine and enamel - i.e. Ivory

I also entertain people

> Houndstooth is a Music Label: https://www.houndstoothlabel.com/

And make your house beautiful

> [Houndstooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houndstooth) is a pattern used in fabric or wallpapers

Comment: Also not correct, the other answers are a little closer.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure this is:

> [Zebrawood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebrawood)

I start with an animal

> Zebra, yes

And finish with a material

> Wood, a material.

I also entertain people

> Guitars are made of it.

And make your house beautiful

> And also [home-decor](https://www.houzz.com/zebrawood-ideas)

Comment: Lol, it's not :) I don't know how you guys didnt get it yet...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel Oh God! Nooooooo....

Answer (score 0):

How about

> Canarywood?

Starts with an animal:

> canary. (sort of)

Ends with a material:

> wood.

Entertain people:

> a google search for "canarywood instrument" suggest at least guitars are made from it

Make your house beautiful:

> canarywood is certainly lovely enough to make furniture out of.

Comment: Nope, thats not it :(