# Tired of me yet?

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

Inspired by [Riley's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) riddle,

> My prefix is a secret,
>
> My suffix sings a stick,
>
> My infix is trouble,
>
> How sad is it.

What am I?

**Hint 1**

> The answer to [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62782/a-question-you-might-ask) is a hint for line two... and it's not a singer.

Comment: Is the title a hint? :)

Comment: Is the title a reference to the number of riddles (seemingly) based on mine recently? Such as [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62606/my-front-was-revered-in-olden-times) and [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62366/i-start-with-an-animal-and-finish-with-a-material)

Comment: @Riley Not at all :]

Comment: @Foitn Not a very helpful one, but when you find the answer you'll see ;)

Comment: isn't a *in* missing in the second line? "sings a stick" sounds really weird

Comment: @Flying_whale "sings in a stick"? now that sounds silly...

Comment: @PaigeMeinke would this have anything to do with "fake news"?

Comment: @Kevin Nope. "Tired of me yet?" is mainly aimed at all the puzzlers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess:

> shadow

My prefix is a secret,

> SHA is a cryptographic function

My suffix sings a stick,

> Based on the other riddle, "dow" for a dowsing rod

My infix is trouble,

> "ado" means confusion or commotion

How sad is it.

> <s>Having a shadow overhead means sadness</s>
> is an anagram for "it is shadow" (Thanks to @OnlyF)

Title

> <s>When you're tired it's usually dark out</s>
> "shadow" is a common answer to riddles

Comment: rot13("ubj fnq vg vf" vf na nantenz bs "vg vf funqbj") methinks, and line 2 should be rot13("qbj" (abg "qbjf"), juvpu fvatf n fgvpx (ebq))...

Comment: I'm totally lost but I added another guess

Comment: @OnlyF I think you posted in the wrong thread

Comment: @Dean, I'm pretty sure I didn't.. have [a look here](http://www.rot13.com/) and try my funny looking guesses, just didn't want to give it away too easily, in case you wanted to guess yourself..

Comment: @OnlyF Ohh you wanted me to ROT13, okay. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @OnlyF rot13(Tbbq pnyy nobhg gur nantenz. Creuncf gurer'f n qbhoyr zrnavat? V gubhtug gur zrnavat jnf gung vg fbhaqf yvxr "fnqqb".)

Answer (score 11):

How about

> Acrostic?

My prefix is a secret,

> An Acrostic poem itself has a secret at the beginning of each line.

My suffix sings a stick,

> Literally "stic."

My infix is trouble,

> to "cross" someone is to make trouble, no?

How sad is it.

> A puzzle whose answer is a type of puzzle?

And the title could refer to

> The numerous puzzles that show up here where the answer is hidden in the first letters of each line, perhaps?

Comment: That's a creative interpretation of the first line, I like it :) but it's not what I was going for, doesn't quite fit for the last line.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be

> **Endemic**?

My prefix is a secret,

> Don't spoil the ending cuz it's a secret

My suffix sings a stick,

> The technical definition of microphone (abbreviated mic) is "a stick that you sing into"

My infix is trouble,

> Dems, Reps... it's my belief that all political parties are trouble ;)

How sad is it.

> An [endemic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/endemic) is a disease that is common to a certain people or area, and that's sad.

Comment: I like the interpretation, that would be a pretty broad description of my infix if it was that though.

Answer (score 4):

Joke answer:

> Puzzlement

Tired of me yet?

> Nope

My prefix is a secret,

> Puzzle solutions are secret to the solver.

My suffix sings a stick,

> While they would probably resent being referred to in the context of sticks, the *ent* Treebeard sings a song to Merry and Pippin.

My infix is trouble,

> The letter 'M' is the 13th letter of the alphabet!

How sad is it.

> Only when the puzzlement dies out or the puzzles run dry.

Comment: Since this is a puzzling site, I don't think people would be tired of your word yet. But I like the creativity!

Answer (score 3):

Here's my attempt

> keypuncher

My prefix is a secret

> "key"; in a cryptographic sense should be kept secret

My suffix sings a stick

> "cher"; Cher is a singer, a stick could be something that "sticks in your head" or alternatively an "earworm", so she sings catchy songs.

My infix is trouble

> "punch"; obviously a punch spells trouble for either the recipient or the sender

How sad is it

> "keypuncher" on urban dictionary may refer to a person which doesn't add any worth to anything they do, or may need handholding to do the most simple of tasks. To be a keypuncher would be quite a sad thing.

Tired of me yet?

> a "keypuncher" as a job is someone who used to make punch cards for old computers. In theory, this is an incredibly boring and monotonous job: one which you'd tire of easily.

Comment: I really like this answer! but that's not it. On the right track for the prefix. I don't think the "stick" part really fits with it though. I'll add a hint for that line.

Answer (score 2):

This will be my first every Stack-Answer, i hope its not to far off:

> postulated

My prefix is a secret,

> Nobody knows whats coming next. "post"

My suffix sings a stick,

> Ed Sheeran sings literaly the word "stick" in the Line:
>  "I'm like glue, I stick to other artists" (Song:You Need Me, I Don't Need You)

My infix is trouble,

> It is always bad when you are late. "ulate"

How sad is it.

> If you believe in something, without knowing if it's true, and you are proven wrong, you will be sad.

If you see any flaws in my writing, please point it out, English is not my first language.

Comment: haha I love the infix, but I don't think anyone would be tired of your word. I probably would have used "sings I stick" if it was that and I wouldn't necessarily call that prefix a secret . Good guess though!

Answer (score 2):

Are you a...

> codemonkey?

```
My prefix is a secret
```

> A **code** is a secret.

```
My suffix sings a stick,
```

> I believe the answer to your other question is "Y", which looks like a tuning fork (i.e. a "singing stick").

```
My infix is trouble,
```

> A **demon** is certainly trouble!

```
How sad is it.
```

> ... to be a lowly code monkey. So sad!

Comment: That word is actually two words...so nope! But nice take

Answer (score 1):

Definitely it's

> *secreting* :D

My prefix is a secret

> well, it is

My suffix sings a stick

> donno, that weird phrase looks like pun relating to the actual suffix of "secreting"

My infix is trouble

> *cretin* person is a trouble for anyone

Also, you can't disagree with the fact that secrets around you annoy you and make you tired.

Comment: Try again! The final line is a clue to the full word as well. Also this doesn't really fit the suffix line.

Comment: I will say that you were on the right track for the suffix.. IT IS a bit of a weird phrase

Answer (score 1):

I could be hopelessly wrong, but is the answer

> sepulcher?

My prefix is a secret

> Not sure about this

My suffix sings a stick

> Cher Lloyd sings the album "Sticks and Stones"

My infix is trouble

> Trouble starts with "T" and that rhymes with "P" which stands for "pul". From the song "Ya got Trouble"

How sad is it

> "sepulcher" is associated with burial, which is sad :(

Comment: Thanks for teaching me a new word, but no, that isn't it!

Answer (score 1):

Could be also

> badmouth

My prefix is a secret

> when you pronounce *bad*,
>  it sounds like *bed*,
>  so it's a secret what you've said :)

My suffix sings a stick

> It's *mouth*, which can be used to play the flute

My infix is trouble

> I can see *ad* in it! Ads are certainly a trouble nowadays :D

How sad is it.

> It's sad when someone criticizes you :(

Comment: The first guess is a stretch, but I like your other interpretations

Answer (score 1):

Perchance:

> Sadistic

My prefix is a secret,

> It is. How sad.

My suffix sings a stick,

> It sings a "stic". ("To sing" can mean to "to give information".)

My infix is trouble,

> "dis-" may refer to a negative force as in "disability", "discontent", and "dislike" and "dis" is slang for "insult".

How sad is it.

> It's not sad at all.

Comment: I don't quite think that prefix is a secret

Comment: But you're on the right track with the line your referenced... Think on it a bit more :)