# In Excess of "IX"es

Tags: word, language

> My prefix? A choice always off'ring the best.
>   My suffix? An action afflicting the rest.
>   My infix? Detectives that take me to test,
>   And speak me out loud, where oft I'm at my best.

Hint:

> I'm wondering where wonderful words went.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Alliteration

My prefix? A choice always off'ring the best.

> All means that you get everything. I.e, All-inclusive **or** "A" is normally the best, A ranked restaurants or A as a grade. EDIT-OP: also, you choose the first letter, the 'prefix,' of a sentence using alliteration.

My suffix? An action afflicting the rest.

> -tion is a suffix that forms nouns of action or condition. EDIT-OP: or "shun," as in "shunning all other letters"

My infix? Detectives that take me to test,

> Liter, I guess you could test a milliliter of blood **OR**  @Statman's suggestion, Literati: Detectives are well educated and might look things up in books

And speak me out loud, where oft I'm at my best.

> Alliterations sounds the best when you say them out loud. They roll off the tongue nicely.

Hint:

> The hint is an alliteration: I'm wondering where wonderful words went.

Comment: This sounds right. Here's an alternative suggestion for the infix: rot13(yvgrengv)

Comment: The answer is right, the justifications aren't what I had in mind (though @Statman 's was!). The prefixes of {*the answer*] was what I was alluding to, similar to an [Acrostic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62726/tired-of-me-yet/62735#62735). Any other ideas for the suffix?

Comment: Didn't realize that was a word @Statman thanks!

Comment: Even smaller...rot13(gur cersvk pubbfrf "n" be "j", naq ????f gur erfg).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer is:

> Superconducting

My prefix? A choice always off'ring the best.

> Super- means above, over, etc.

My suffix? An action afflicting the rest.

> -ducting - means to convey or channel by means of a duct or ducts. The superconductor conducts electricity. A system of ducts can conduct a lot of other things.

My infix? Detectives that take me to test,

> -con- The cops will definitely be putting to the test something they suspect is a con operation.

And speak me out loud, where oft I'm at my best.

> And a superconductor is the best possible conductor.

Comment: No, sorry. The detectives "take me to test *and* speak me out loud."