# A question you might ask

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> I’m a question you might ask
>
> I’m a broken wish that’s small
>
> I’m mail that gets sent last
>
> I add a southern feel to all
>
> I’m a fork that you'll divine
>
> but use only sometimes

What am I?

-- The answer will be a hint to line 2 of [Tired of me yet?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62726/tired-of-me-yet)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Y

I’m a question you might ask

> Why?

I’m a broken wish that’s small

> A wishbone is small, Y-shaped, and broken to make a wish

I’m mail that gets sent last

> Mail->Male-> XY chromosomes. Y is last in "XY"

I add a southern feel to all

> y+all = y'all

I’m a fork that you'll divine

> A divining rod is Y-shaped

but use only sometimes

> Y is sometimes a vowel

Comment: It might be letter, but it's not quite last then.

Comment: mail ~ male = XY, Y being last chromosome?

Comment: it's pretty close to last. and @Jordan.J.D is right too

Comment: @PaigeMeinke Did it!

Answer (score 2):

Continuing on from **[Robert C's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43783/robert-c)**'s answer, I would choose to finish this.

> Y

I’m a question you might ask

> Why?

I’m a broken wish that’s small

> A wishbone is small, Y-shaped, and broken to make a wish

I’m mail that gets sent last

> **The word mail sounds like male, which's alleles are XY. The last letter of this is a Y**

I add a southern feel to all

> y+all = y'all

I’m a fork that you'll divine

> A diving rod is Y-shaped

but use only sometimes

> Y is sometimes a vowel

Comment: @RobertC Do you want me to add any more attribution?

Comment: Looks good to me!