# The Worst Performing Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, affix-riddle

<sup>*Inspired by [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/25802), and co-inspired by [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62726/25802).*</sup>

> My prefix is unused clutter.
> My suffix doesn't sound merely cool.
> My infix doesn't tick or <s>talk</s> tock.
> I leave a lot to be desired. (11)

**What am I?**

Hint:

> A term from American culture that has made its way into the dictionary.

Comment: `I leave a lot to be desired (11).` Does this mean the solution has 11 characters ?

Comment: @Abhishek, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is

> Craptacular

My prefix is unused clutter.

> Crap, speaks for itself..

My suffix isn't merely cool

> tacular, pretty much the only word with that suffix is spectacular, which isn't just "merely cool"..

My infix doesn't tick or tock.

> Not too sure, maybe it tac's instead?

I leave a lot to be desired

> Craptacular means "remarkably poor or disappointing"..

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> **Trashy** ?

My prefix is a dump

> It's Trash

My suffix isn't merely cool

> Shy = Not cool?

My infix doesn't tick or talk

> 

I leave something to be desired

> Being *trashy* is being mediocre/inferior/imperfect (leaving something to be desired)

Comment: I guess you could say that that the infix doesn't tick or talk either. (the middle four letters)

Comment: No parts are correct, but trash is very close. Note that I listed the number of letters for the answer. I'll add another hint soon.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about this, don't think it ticks all the boxes, but....

Is it:

> Bingewatcher (it was recently added to the dictionary)

Prefix is a dump:

> Bin

My infix doesn't tick or talk:

> Watch, but not the ticking kind

My suffix isn't merely cool:

> Cher? I guess some people think she's cool. Yeah I'm not sure about this bit.

Comment: It's a recently added word much like this, but not this one. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> **Throw shade**. It's an expression recently added from American slang that made it into the dictionay last year I believe.

My prefix is unused clutter.

> I do belive that before the edit you said something about a dumpster, but it qualifies anyways since unused clutter you **throw** away.

My suffix doesn't sound merely cool.

> Shade is cool, colder than everything on the sun.

My infix doesn't tick or talk.

> Since they are two words, the infix is a space, so it doesn't talk

I leave a lot to be desired (11).

> "Throw shade" is eleven characters counting the space in between and also it can mean to express "contempt"

Comment: Nice thinking outside the box, but there's no space or silence. It's a single word. And you can see the edits by clicking on the "edited" link next to my name (https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/62825/revisions).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it's this, but just for fun:

> Wastewater

My prefix is unused clutter.

> Waste: things that are unused just go to waste

My suffix doesn't sound merely cool.

> Water: Water sounds pretty awesome as it falls - also, can be cold or hot

My infix doesn't tick or talk tock.

> Stew doesn't tick or talk or tock

I leave a lot to be desired (11).

> Literally no one has any desire to drink wastewater

Comment: This was a good answer, just not the one I was looking for.