# Another Riley riddle, not as good as I'd hoped

Tags: riddle, geography

Inspiration [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62825/39764), [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62726/39764), and the [original](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/25802).

> Put down my prefix.
>
> Put on my suffix.
>
> You can't see my infix for the trees.
>
> If I had a cape, it would look like this:
>
> [image: Status of a goddess it would spoil the puzzle to name]
>   Image from [benjamindavidsteele.wordpress.com](https://benjamindavidsteele.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/columbia-goddess-of-america/)
>
> What am I?

Hint #1:

> If I were an an island, I'd be nominally in Auckland.

Hint #2:

> The answer is suggested by the title.

Comment: I propose that these puzzles are officially named "Riley riddles".

Comment: Or perhaps "Rileyddles"

Comment: I vote for *rileyddles*!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are:

> Disappointment.

Put down my prefix:

> diss: to diss is to insult or “put down”

Put on my suffix:

> ointment: ointment is something that is "put on" (thanks @Chowzen in the comments)

You can’t see my infix for the trees:

> sap: “Can’t see the wood for the trees” is an expression. “sap” is found inside trees.

If I had a cape, it would look like this:

> The image is of the goddess Columbia (per the website linked). [Cape Disappointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Disappointment_(Washington)) is the cape on the north of the Columbia River.

Hint 1:

> Disappointment Island is part of the Auckland archipelago.

Hint 2:

> Not as good as I hoped: a disappointment.

Comment: Very close. Not quite right on the postfix, and you haven't explained the cape.

Comment: @RupertMorrish have added an explanation for the cape.

Comment: The suffix that you put on may be "ointment," right?

Comment: Thanks @Chowzen, that makes more sense than my version!

Comment: There is also $\ast$ (ROT13) Acibh Rwgoddcwbhasbh $\ast$ (go [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=mount+disappointment&oq=mount+disappointment&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l5.2605j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

Answer (score 0):

An attempt at an answer:

Is it:

> **San Andres**?

Put down my prefix

> Put-down can be interpreted as without (i.e) **San**s

Put on my suffix.

> Put-on or wear a **dres**s maybe?

You can't see my infix for the trees.

> 

Comment: No to all three guesses, I'm afraid.