# My front was revered in olden times

Tags: riddle, word

**My front was revered in olden times.**
**My back brings life to many.**
**My middle is not really correct.**
**What am I?**

*Hint 1*

> I can be described as a thing on my own, or as a feature of something else.

*Hint 2*

> `My middle is not really correct.` refers to the partial word, but can be taken quite literally too.

*Hint 3*

> Similar to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/42517), the words contained in the solution may overlap.

Answer (score 14):

A speculative second look. A convoluted explanation that the word may be

> **aspect**

My front was revered in olden times.

> **asp** - in ancient Egypt, one of several venomous snakes which was a symbol of royalty, including the Egyptian cobra represented by the revered goddess [Meretseger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meretseger).

My back brings life to many.

> **[ECT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECT)** -  Electrochemotherapy or Electroconvulsive therapy may be said to bring life to quite a few.

My middle is not really correct.

> **Spec** - Wikipedia gives this as short for [Speculative evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_evolution), which is not the accepted natural evolution. This page says: *'However, speculative biology is not the same as **xenobiology** —it is a larger, distinct concept, which includes the alternate evolution of life in any scenario, terrestrial or extraterrestrial'*. What prompted this answer was [Orphevs's profile](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/42517/orphevs) - a Xenobiology artist!!!

*Hint 1*

> *I can be described as a thing on my own, or as a feature of something else.*
>
>  The definition of *aspect* - a particular part or feature of something.

*Hint 2*

> *My middle is not really correct. refers to the partial word, but can be taken quite literally too.*
>
>  'Spec.' is an abbreviation so is not literally correct as well as not scientifically correct.

---

*Attempt 1:* A quick thought is you are a

> **racer** - an animal/vehicle for a speed contest or a gun carriage's rail.

My front was revered in olden times.

> Ra - the Egyptian sun god.

My back brings life to many.

> ER - Emergency Room - resuscitation and in general saving lives.

My middle is not really correct.

> c - circa abbreviation for approximately preceding a date.

Comment: I like this answer very much, Tom. It's not quite what I intended, but very good nonetheless. One third of your answer is on the right path, you just need to look for a different, more general term in the same field.

Comment: I think this is a bit of a stretch, especially given the hint in the OP.

Comment: I concur - this is quite a mindbender -  I may  think on!

Comment: @Tom I like your second solution better than my intended one, on par with David Foong's answer. As per https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2879, I will think of hints that limit the possible solutions further. A puzzle on its own to not give away the solution right away, if you will :)

Comment: @Orphevs -  I'm further intrigued. This is a thoroughbred three pipe problem!

Comment: @Tom let's just hope that it isn't hard to solve because I'm no native speaker :) Either way I hope it's enjoyable.

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> Godparent?

My front was revered in olden times.

> Gods were revered

My back brings life to many.

> Parents birth kids

My middle is not really correct.

> Par -> para, greek word meaning something like "not correct". There's a little leap in logic here. Maybe it's not correct because it's supposed to be para?

I can be described as a thing on my own, or as a feature of something else.

> You can be a single parent or a couple.

My middle is not really correct. refers to the partial word, but can be taken quite literally too.

> Again, a little bit of a leap but para means not normal, par is literally not par as well. Overall I'm a little hesitant about this answer.

Comment: Great answer, but not what I intended. 1 is on the right path, 2 not really, 3 is conceptually similar to what I intended.

Comment: Note also that Hint 1 does not go well with this.

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer... just a guess...

> Pacer

My front was revered in olden times

> Pa is generally used for pascal (the SI unit of pressure, which was named after the French polymath Blaise Pascal - who was quite a revered personality in the 1600's).

The rest of the answer is same as [that of Tom](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62628/38170).

Comment: Not correct sadly. Please note that I wrote one third of Tom's answer was on the right path - never was it stated that any part of Tom's answer would be correct as it is.

Comment: Ok .. for sure .. will look for the same  @orphevs