# An eight letter word this time, what am I?

Tags: riddle

Inspired by Riley's Riddle: [My prefix is food, my suffix is rude](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude)

> My prefix is what kids desire
>
> My suffix by all means isn't zero
>
> My infix proposes a Latin successor
>
> I'm a relationship students often neglect

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the word

> Function

My prefix is what kids desire

> Fun

My suffix by all means isn't zero

> Ion? Maybe because they are either positive or negative but never 0

My infix proposes a Latin successor

> "uncti" is Latin for anointed, which fits a "proposed successor"(Thanks @OnlyF :D)

I'm a relationship students often neglect

> A function is a relationship in algebra

Comment: You're on the right track. You're almost there!

Comment: Which part is the closest? :D

Comment: rot13("hapgv" vf Yngva sbe nabvagrq, juvpu svgf n "cebcbfrq fhpprffbe"), is probably the solution to the infix?

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie OnlyF is correct about the remaining part. Please add it to your answer but I will give you the accept