# Tag! You're it! :)

Tags: knowledge

Everyone should {my prefix} that an {my infix}, like most others of its type, can easily perch on a {my suffix}.

> What's the word?

Comment: I thought that they were **true** prefixes, infixes and suffixes.

Comment: None of the puzzles of this nature that I've seen contained actual [infixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix): "English has almost no true infixes (as opposed to tmesis), and those it does have are marginal. A few are heard in [colloquial speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix#Colloquialisms), and a few more are found in technical terminology."

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, at least the middle would be easier to figure out!

Comment: @user3306356, the usual words are beginning, end and middle, of course, but OP is paying homage to [this double gold badge earning puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/36023)

Comment: Bird's the word! :O I guess that is kinda a hint also

Comment: @user3306356 True infixes are too sophistimacated to actually use them properly in a puzzle ☺️

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The word is

> Knowledge. Everyone should **know** that an **owl**, like many others of its type,  can easily perch on a **ledge**. Too easy, shouldn't have made the answer the tag :) Just realized the title gives that away too, nice.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw "12 When should the knowledge tag be used?" over on the sidebar under HOT META POSTS and thought it would be funny!

Comment: So is this technically a misuse of the tag? The misclassification of this riddle is the entire point!

Comment: @Riley Well you do need to know that {infix}s perch on {suffix}s, so it does technically require some knowledge.