# My prefix is called an island

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My prefix is called an island.
>   My infix is an island.
>   My suffix is not so windy.
>   I made this puzzle.
>
> Who am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Riley

My prefix is called an island.

> The island of [Rye](https://www.britannica.com/place/Great-Rye-Island), or the state code for Rhode Island, USA (RI).

My infix is an island.

> ile, sounds like isle

My suffix is not so windy.

> ley, not so windy as in "using or expressed in many words that sound impressive but mean little", indeed, it is very short.

Or

> lee, as in "protective shelter", more likely to be the intended answer to the clue :)

I made this puzzle.

> [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566/riley), the first to drop [one of these types of riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) here..

Comment: You are correct, but your first and third clues are off.

Comment: At least they’re not what I had in mind

Comment: Ok, I have given them some more thought now..

Comment: Your new explanations are what I was thinking. Good job!

Comment: To be clear to readers Rhode Island is correct because it’s “called an island” but not really one and fits better spelling-wise.