# The Riley Channel

Tags: riddle, affix-riddle

*<sup>In an effort to honor the '[Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/25802)' better than my last, I've created one that sticks (without rhyme) to the original structure:</sup>*

> My prefix is us.
>
> My suffix is a woman.
>
> My infix is consuming.
>
> I am the heavens come to Earth.

**What am I?**

Comment: Is there a Riley Podcast, too? :D $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is the answer

> Weather

My prefix is us.

> We

My suffix is a woman.

> Her

My infix is consuming.

> Eat

I am the heavens come to Earth.

> Nice Weather?

Comment: Also of note is the title is The Riley Channel, or The Weather Channel. Good job!

Comment: not necesarrily nice, heavens refers to the contents of the sky, be it fair or stormy.

Comment: @Jasen, yes. That was the intended meaning.