# Riley Riddle #359

Tags: riddle, word

I'm jumping on the bandwagon.

> My prefix comes before.
>   My suffix is a cure.
>   My infix knows the rules.
>   Now answer this, you fools!

Comment: Hey, finally someone made one that rhymes like the [original](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude)! (depending on your pronunciation of "cure")

Comment: @Riley well, when I made [my first Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69303/my-prefix-is-a-formula-my-suffix-being-shared), I tried to be original. Perhaps I'll make some more, and this time, keep to the traditions :D

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The answer is:

> **Prefix**? ( *M E T A* )

My prefix comes before.

> Comes before => Prefix or **Pre**

My suffix is a cure.

> **Fix**

My infix knows the rules.

> The **ref** knows the rules

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: @OnlyF Considering the fact that my heart skipped a beat when Sid answered... I get you... :)

Comment: You're no fool.

Answer (score 9):

I think it is

> Prefix

My prefix comes before.

> Pre, comes before many words

My suffix is a cure.

> fix, is a cure

My infix knows the rules.

> ref, knows the rules

Answer (score 4):

This is a shady attempt. I think it is:

> PREPILL.

Prefix:

> Comes before=pre

Suffix:

> A pill tends to be a cure.

Infix:

> This is the shady part. Supposedly someone with a lot of REP knows the rules?