# Will Riley Riddles ever end?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

*Maybe, maybe not — but the answer won't.*

---

> My prefix is the first half of what was before.
>
> My suffix curses Scotland in red and no more.
>
> My infix is a hotshot when scrambled (what egg?).
>
> I am twice my definition; I begin with a beg.

**What am I?**

---

**Hint:**

> The answer to the riddle can be found in front of you, 
>  Including all the clues except the second one through. 
>  
>  The pun is quite a hint — the answer is in every word! 
>  In the riddle, it is seen; in the beginning, it is heard.

Comment: does the word actually start with beg? or is that just a wordplay

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid I think it's just wordplay cos' if it isn't, OP wouldn't write the prefix part. BTW,@user477343, nice riddle, mate. Always enjoyed yours :)

Comment: To the title: I hope so ;-)

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid no it doesn't start with "beg" ... but that is still a clue. The last line talks about the *definition* of the word.

Comment: ***Ftq mzeiqd omz mxea nq ragzp*** [***tqdq***](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62931/riley-riddle-359?rq=1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are

> Prefix

My prefix is the first half of what was before.

> Literally, **pre** (The word 'prefix' come before in the sentence and half of it is 'pre' and pre = before)

My suffix curses Scotland in red and no more.

> Curse of Scotland = 9 of Diamond. 9 in Roman numerals is **ix**

My infix is a hotshot when scrambled (what egg?).

> When you scramble **refi**, you get 'fire' which is literally hot.

I am twice my definition; I begin with a beg.

> Prefix of begin is beg. Hence, begin begins with a beg.

Comment: 'Tis true! You got it correct! Well done! Also, (ROT13) n jbeq gb ercynpr "jung jnf orsber" vf "cerivbhf", juvpu jnf jung V vavgvnyyl nvzrq sbe; ohg unys bs gung vf "ceri", fb lbhe qrfpevcgvba sbe gur cersvk svgf orggre! Naq, sver vf ubg naq fubgf pna or sverq, gb znxr "ubgfubg". Apart from those minor details, congratulations! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: Love this riddle and the hint too. Very clever! :)

Answer (score 4):

I still don't have a solution, but I think the prefix might be

> pa (the first half of "past")

and the suffix something related to

> the Nine of Diamonds card, since its nickname is "the curse of Scotland"... so, either "nine", or "NoD", or "card".

Comment: I’ve had the same conclusions. The only word I could find was “pavonine”

Comment: Reversing your second suggestion for the suffix doesn't really make sense, but it would give you a word that goes well with "beg".

Comment: @MOehm Ahh, I see what you mean - but I also don't see why it would be reversed... and I don't think it explains all the lines - 3rd, for example.

Comment: @tyobrien the answer is not pavonine because the infix is not "pa", though you have the right idea. Find another word other than "past". Hint: Rot13(Vg fgnegf jvgu C). But you have the suffix correct, though it is not "nine", but something else equal to nine...

Comment: I have added a hint :)