# Don't Know What to Call This Anymore

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My prefix is where you may live outside your house
>
> Though it can be very uncomfortable if you're not used to it
>
> My infix is what you should never ever touch
>
> It might just end your life in an instant
>
> My suffix is what you can use to call your pet
>
> But if your mind's dirty, you may mistake me for *that* **other one** :)

Hint 1 :

> Almost everyone will eventually go to (*The Word*)

Hint 2 :

> The word itself is a place you can stay

To clarify :

> The **last line** is about the **suffix**
>
> The **Note** has nothing to do with the riddle
>
> The title also has nothing to do with the riddle (I just ran out of ideas :D)

Note :

> Sorry if you think this is not appropriate, but that is not what I meant by the last line **at all**

Comment: (ROT13) uggcf://chmmyvat.fgnpxrkpunatr.pbz/dhrfgvbaf/62960/na-rqhpngrq-evyrl?ed=1 Gur nafjre va gur yvax vf gur fnzr :C

Comment: @user477343 Wow, didn't realize that question had the same answer lol :D

Comment: In [this Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70052/will-riley-riddles-ever-end) of mine, it had the same answer as [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62931/riley-riddle-359?noredirect=1&lq=1), too, hahah :P

Comment: @user477343 so many similar answers in this site :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Studying around here I think you are a

> **campus**

My prefix is where you may live outside your house, though it can be very uncomfortable ...

> camp - as in a base.

My infix is what you should never ever touch
It might just end your life in an instant

> amp - especially if high power.

My suffix is what you can use to call your pet, but if your mind's dirty, you may mistake me for ...

> pus  - I'm ashamed to say this was my lead in.

Comment: Okay well, we don't judge here. +1 from me, but _only because the suffix was your lead-in_ ;)

Comment: @El-Guest the first thing I thought of was, *there's a snake in my boot!* xD

Comment: Wow, this is the correct answer :) Well Played. Gonna wait for a while before accepting ur answer :D @Tom

Comment: U know what? I'm just gonna accept this and start making a new one. There!

Answer (score 4):

Still haven't figured out all the clues, but I'm thinking of

> Tentacle

Prefix

> Tent

Infix

> AC as in AC current

Suffix

> Not sure about this one.

Also

> Tentacle has some dirty connotations to it.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not the intended answer :)

Comment: Btw, your first part is almost (ALMOST) correct but not the intended word :)

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> Welcome ?

My prefix is where you may live outside your house

Though it can be very uncomfortable if you're not used to it

> There is a proverb "Like a frog in a well" and a story too about a frog who lived in a well. It's a nice story though.

My infix is what you should never ever touch

It might just end your life in an instant

> This might be a stretch but the infix is el, can be treated as eel? Eel blood is poisonous to humans and can kill you. Also some eels are known to electrocute other animals.

My suffix is what you can use to call your pet

But if your mind's dirty, you may mistake me for that other one :)

> My mind is dirty...... Normally when we call pets, a dog in this example, we use "Come here, *insert name of pet*", but really. My mind is just dirty.

I know the note has some significance but I'm not sure about it yet

Comment: Nope, that's incorrect :)

Comment: I shall try again soon!

Comment: Yep, that's the spirit :D

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to say the answer is

> Innuendo

But I'm not able to associate it well with all lines

My prefix is where you may live outside your house
Though it can be very uncomfortable if you're not used to it

> inn

My infix is what you should never ever touch
It might just end your life in an instant

> 'uend' is the infix -> u end -> you end -> your life ends?

My suffix is what you can use to call your pet

> 

But if your mind's dirty, you may mistake me for that other one

> Innuendo is used to make innocent words seem dirty

Comment: Unfortunately wrong :)

Comment: Regarding the suffix, perhaps (ROT13) Vg pbhyq or RAQB, juvpu vf fubeg sbe RAQBGUREZVP, zrnavat "jnez-oybbqrq navznyf" (r.t. n enoovg). Gung vapyhqrf fb znal navznyf, vg pbhyq rira or lbhe crg! :D

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is a bit of a stretch, but could the answer be

> **CIRCUITIES**?

`My prefix is where you may live outside your house`

> **CIRC** $\to$ CIRCUS $\to$ CIRCUS TENT $\to$ TENT.

`Though it can be very uncomfortable if you're not used to it`

> You might become **homesick**, or just simply not enjoy the experience.

`My infix is what you should never ever touch`

> **IT**, as in **Pennywise** the Dancing Clown.

`It might just end your life in an instant`

> **IT** might just end your life in an instant.

`My suffix is what you can use to call your pet`

> You can use a **SELECTION** of names to call your pet (for which the word starts with the suffix, **S**, and there are plenty of names that start with S, too).

`But if your mind's dirty, you may mistake me for that other one :)`

> **S** can also stand for a whole range of dirty things, from things that are *actually* dirty (like **SH**$\ast\ast$ because you are picking up your pet's doodoo) and things that are just dirty (like **SEX**, because you are referring to the gender of your pet). 
>  
>  Especially the line, *there's a* ***s***${}$*nake in my boot!*

---

**Title:**

`Don't Know What to Call This Anymore`

> This is an example of a **circuity**, as it lacks straightforwardness (since the title should be along the lines of "Riley Riddle" perhaps?). Nonetheless, the hints indicate that the word, **circuities**, is not the answer, anyways...

Comment: Not the correct answer, unfortunately but good try (+1) :) Btw, the title is not related (I just ran out of ideas) :D

Comment: @KevinL I think this is one of the toughest of your Riley Riddles, thus far :D

Comment: Really? Thanks mate. I'm thinking of starting yet another bounty on this tomorrow :D Edit : The prefix (as I have said in a comment to sedrick) is almost correct. You just gotta [Hint] {Rot13} (svaq nabgure jbeq jvgu nyzbfg gur fnzr zrnavat) :D

Comment: @KevinL If you want, you can remind me of this question tomorrow and I'll see if I can put a bounty up, as I have more reputation than you :D

Comment: Wow, thanks. I guess I'll see whether someone comes up with the correct answer tomorrow :)

Comment: Just realised the anagram explanation was a miscalculation :P ... but after that Rot13 hint, I will still give this another crack :D

Comment: Sure, I encourage you to get the correct answer :D

Comment: @KevinL ah wait! Is the prefix Rot13(uhg)? I think this is it :D

Comment: Nope :D @user477343

Comment: @KevinL oh wait above is the correct answer?? How dd I not *think* of that! *Facepalm*.

Comment: Lol yeah Tom gave the correct answer :)

Comment: @KevinL I love these kinds of riddles. You think of all these things and then simple answers, you don't think yourself. (At least for me, that is). And sorry for this delayed reply. I had a quick shower :P

Comment: Lol no problemo :)