# Affixes on steroids

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

Since I made the [original](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) "Riley riddle", there have been many other riddles of the same form. So, of course, I thought it was very important to take this to its logical extreme. Sorry this one doesn't rhyme :)

> My prefix comes through my prefix's suffix.
>
> My suffix eats my prefix's suffix's suffix.
>
> My prefix's prefix isn't real.
>
> My prefix's suffix's suffix's prefix is it?

What am I?

Comment: I have to say that sounds pretty funny :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Are you...

> important?

My prefix comes through my prefix's suffix.

> An **import** comes through a **port**.

My suffix eats my prefix's suffix's suffix.

> An **ant** can eat an [**ort**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ort).

My prefix's prefix isn't real.

> **i** is an [imaginary unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit).

My prefix's suffix's suffix's prefix is it?

> **or** is it?
>
>  [From Riley's comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62946/affixes-on-steroids#comment191767_62955), the last two phrases combine to make "**i** isn't real. **or** is it?"

Comment: You got it! You're really close on the last clue. Can you figure it out?

Comment: @Riley: Is that it?

Comment: The last two clues make rot13("v vfa'g erny. Be vf vg?"). You got the right phrase.

Comment: @Riley: Ah, I see now.

Answer (score 4):

Having so many prefixes and suffixes, it has to be

> [PenPineappleApplePen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0E00Zuayv9Q)

My prefix comes through my prefix's suffix.

> According to the video clip, it does indeed (no matter what exactly, in that word any pen comes through any fruit)

My prefix's prefix isn't real.

> If you consider prefix to be *penpineappleapple* or *penpineapple*, then I can say for sure such word doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry, this isn't correct. All of the clues will make sense with the correct answer.