# An Educated Riley

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

Another one in the '[Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/25802)' theme:

> My prefix is where the soldiers stayed.
>
> My suffix is from a bandaid.
>
> My infix flows with the current.
>
> I am where things should be learnt.

Comment: If we eliminate all places where things should not be learnt finding the answer should be easy :)

Comment: @Jasen, lol. That's one way!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's

> CAMPUS?

*My prefix is where the soldiers stayed.*

> Soldiers stay in a CAMP.

*My suffix is from a bandaid.*

> Perhaps there is PUS leaking under your bandaid?

*My infix flows with the current.*

> Electrical current is measured in AMPs.

*I am where things should be learnt.*

> On a university CAMPUS.

Comment: That *is* the answer. Nice job.