# My start will cause annoyance

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> My start will cause annoyance
>   My end lines: not real science
>   French island is my middle
>   I once composed a riddle

Who am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is of course

> Riley

My start will cause annoyance

> Rile

My end lines: not real science

> ley = something to do with paranormal "lines of energy"

French island is my middle

> ile

I once composed a riddle

> The now infamous [My prefix is food, my suffix is rude](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude)

Comment: How is it infamous though? I'd say the opposite.

Comment: "my end lines" -> "[*ley* lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_line)"

Answer (score 4):

I think you are:

> Riley

As for the explanation Statman gave a much better one so I will not edit mine anymore.

My start will cause annoyance

> R-r-r-r is a sound of annoyance, grudge and a lot of other emotions

My end lines: not real science

> Still working on it

French island is my middle

> Ile is French for island

I once composed a riddle

> And yes, Riley, started all this.

Comment: Damn, one minute too late!

Comment: @Statman Technically he gave the answer before you but you gave the explanations first :)