# A Traveling Riley

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, geography, affix-riddle

Easy one in the '[Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/25802)' tradition:

> My prefix is unused.
>
> My suffix is a forest removed.
>
> My infix is a reunited analogue.
>
> I am all alone but for a dog.

Comment: Just to make sure, analogue, not analog, right?

Comment: @PaigeMeinke, right.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke, I waffled on which form to use but went with *ue* because I felt *analog* might be misleading to technical people. I personally use them in different ways, but technically they're supposed to be interchangeable. Good question. https://english.stackexchange.com/a/206959/185028

Comment: Cool cool, just wanted to make sure 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He is in

> `New-found-land`

My prefix is unused.

> Unused is *new*.

My suffix is a forest removed.

> A forest removed is just *land*.

My infix is a reunited analogue.

> An analogue of being reunited is *found*.

I am all alone but for a dog.

> Newfoundland is all alone because it is an island, but does have its [Labrador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newfoundland_and_Labrador) for company!

Comment: That's weird. I don't think I'm there but I guess I must be given how well it fits with the riddle! :)

Comment: @Riley, hahaha. I hope you've been enjoying these. I enjoy this riddle type. When I'm reading now I tend to look more closely at word constructions because of them. Maybe now you'll have to visit Newfoundland and tell us how it is!

Comment: Good job Amit. Hope you don't mind the edits for more clarity.

Answer (score 5):

I guess Riley has been to...

> Newark, or [Newark-on-Trent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newark-on-Trent), England.

*My prefix is unused.*

> We called an unused thing as "a **new** thing".

*My suffix is a forest removed.*

> The flood is coming, cut down all the woods to make an **ark**!

*My infix is a reunited analogue.*

> Unite all the manpower to engage a **war**.

*I am all alone but for a dog.*

> Well, there is *one* new built ark, so it is *alone*.
>  
>  However, there is a [place](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Newark+Showground/@53.0800884,-0.8095732,13.5z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x48784b3d4ebfad3b:0x26919ac4feb35d37!8m2!3d53.098385!4d-0.768045) that held a [dog show](http://www.allaboutdogsshow.co.uk/newark/) not far from the downtown area.

Comment: I like it, but not correct. +1

Comment: I can confirm I've never been there in my life :)

Comment: Omg @Riley I am only to make opening being consistent with the title, hope you don't mind that :)

Comment: I wished I could have said new was correct, but it feels like I'm giving too much of the puzzle away. Good answer.