# I am beautiful to look at

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

I thought I'd try a '[Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude)':

> My prefix you sit on.
> My suffix you swat at.
> My infix you walk on,
> But I am beautiful to look at.

**What am I?**

(It doesn't really rhyme if all the words are the same though, does it?!)

Comment: [Here's an opinion that I found.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45712/does-a-word-rhyme-with-itself)

Comment: ...and you guys thought that this place was just for *puzzles!*

Comment: "So it violates the rules of artfulness." - me in a nutshell :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are:

> Butterfly

Prefix:

> Butt (you sit on)

Suffix:

> Fly (you swat at)

Infix:

> Terf (turf) (you walk on)

Comment: Ah I was 2 seconds too late! Nice work

Comment: Wow! Apparently I need to be more cryptic in my clues. :) Nice job, both of you.

Comment: I almost posted just the answer to then edit in the explanation, but I thought that might be cheating, so I just typed fewer letters!  You probably started before me.

Comment: @Buildstarted Since there was another (different kind) puzzle with this answer posted recently, the word was present in short-term memory.

Comment: Hah! At least someone solved one of my puzzles :)

Comment: @NetJohn I almost did the same thing, too

Comment: @Aces [*"Great minds think alike."*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70536/a-resurrected-riley-riddle)

Answer (score 5):

Is it:

> Butterfly?

my prefix you sit on:

> butt

my suffix you swat at:

> fly

my infix you walk on

> terf (like turf)

but i am beautiful to look at

> a butterfly is nice to look at