# A Resurrected Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

I made a new Riley Riddle to make up for the laziness in [my previous Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70443/feast-your-eyes-on-a-riley-riddle), also inspired by [@KevinL's Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70504/these-riddles-again).

> My prefix won't stand, but it cracks at the bottom.
>
> My suffix has heads in the clouds, not forgotten.
>
> My infix is land, but no flowers can blossom.
>
> My body has legs in a shroud, then wings open.

**What am I?**

The answer is $9$ letters, and the title is a clue. For the last part, I can include the `knowledge` tag... but as a hint, I won't — once you solve for the affixes, you will most likely know of the last line.

Comment: Nice riddle dude :)

Comment: @KevinL thank you very much. Your riddle was also very good, that of which inspired me to write this one, so thank you again :))

Comment: Hint: I could of used the word "unforgotten", but I think "not forgotten" sounds better in this rhyme; feel free to replace phrases with single words :)

Comment: Nah I actually agree with u. It does sound kind of better for me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this a

> BUTTERFLY?

My prefix won't stand, but it cracks at the bottom.

> Haha, you said **BUTT**!! (Although it can't stand by itself, *haha you said buttcrack!*)

My suffix has heads in the clouds, not forgotten.

> Although we'd like to forget about a **FLY**, we can't because *waiter, they're in my soup again*.

My infix is land, but no flowers can blossom.

> This would be  <strike>SURF AND</strike>  **TURF**, where if flowers blossom you're doing it wrong.

My body has legs in a shroud, then wings open.

> This is the BUTTERFLY coming out of its chrysalis and opening its wings, a sort of resurrected caterpillar. (What, you were expecting a fourth joke?) ;)

Comment: And @El-Guest strikes again!

Comment: @user477343 Stay tuned for semi-humorous explanations! ;P

Comment: You are good at answering these... have you made one yourself?

Comment: And I was sure the prefix would be rot13(rtt)...

Comment: @jafe that was my first thought too, I actually used the final line and title to find the word first, and then had to backfill the affixes to overcome the cognitive dissonance!

Comment: @user477343 I'm a reasonably useless puzzle writer, so I definitely appreciate the creativity and cleverness of all of our puzzlers who can write as well as solve them! ;P Never done one before haha!

Comment: Hahahah xD love this answer! Unfortunately, I have once again reached my daily voting limit (don't believe me? I'll send you a pic!) and I can't upvote until $11$ hours have past. By then, you will get the tick! :D

Comment: I love how quickly you spread the votes around! @user477343! If you run out of upvotes are you also not allowed to accept answers? (I've never written a question on here so I have no idea what the mechanism is haha)

Comment: No I still think I can accept answers, but I remember with one of my very first riddles that users have told me to wait a little while before I accept the answer. It gives other users time to work on the puzzle them-selves, and I could also get more views and thus more upvotes. Personally, I don't care about reputation. If it degrades, the only reason I would care is because I would fear I did something wrong to the community. I could accept the answer now if I wanted to... but perhaps you might not receive as many upvotes, as well. idk, that is just my opinion. Want me to accept now?

Comment: @jafe Oohh, that also fits. Perhaps you can find a word starting with that? At least you tried :)

Comment: @user477343 No, I just had no idea about what the rules were from a question-writer's perspective. Personally, I think waiting a bit is the best practice (I've heard several puzzlers far more senior to this site than I advocate for it). Reputation or not, I'd much prefer that your question gets the viewing time from the community that it merits (you deserve it more than I because your creativity is more valuable!!). I think your original plan of 11 hours is the best one! At any rate, another great puzzle! :D

Comment: Thank you!! I also think I say "I have reached my daily voting limit" a bit too much nowadays... so I'll make a rule: whenever I say DVL$n$ for some number $n$, that would mean I have reached my daily voting limit and have to wait $n$ hours before it is over. Just in case I make more Riley Riddles and you answer more of 'em, too :D

Comment: Ooh acronyms! A good means of knowing you're becoming a senior puzzler here ;)

Comment: Sorry... Saturdays are massive for me; I am really busy on those days. Congratulations! $(+1)$ $\color{green}{\checkmark}$