# C'mon, Pucker up!

Tags: riddle

[Rileyism](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) #47

My prefix takes you down.
My suffix picks you up.
My infix Lets you be,
So shut up and kiss me.

Hint(s):

> My prefix *
>  My suffix is a digit
>  My infix *
>  While Kissing, do not fidget.
>  (*coming soon, if needed)

Comment: Rileyism questions are so fun but so hard :(((((

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Mistletoe

My prefix takes you down.

> *Mis-* is a prefix added to verbs to imply an action done wrongly, a possible demotion of the action. 
>  Alternatively *mistle* sounds like missile which could be used to take something down.

My suffix picks you up.

> *Toe* sounds like tow (as in tow truck)

My infix Lets you be,

> Let

So shut up and kiss me.

> Kissing under the mistletoe is a tradition at Christmas time.

Hint

> A toe is a digit at the end of a foot.

Comment: Congratulations @hexomino on the 20K and even more so on the quality of your posts!

Comment: Thank you, @Tom. I see you are not far off the same mark which is good because you have made many valuable contributions to the site over the last few years.

Answer (score 9):

I really don't think this is it but, just to get things started.

Answer:

> buttercup

My prefix takes you down.

> Butt - where you sit down

My suffix picks you up.

> cup (of coffee) - quite the pick-me-up

My infix Lets you be,

> utter - adjective that does not really change the meaning of the noun it modifies.

So shut up and kiss me.

> along with the title, references the old phrase "Pucker up buttercup"

Comment: Not what I had in mind, but a nice try!

Comment: @Chowzen can you specify what part doesn't fit correctly so that way he knows where he went wrong in his thinking? :]

Comment: @PaigeMeinke OK... The prefix, suffix, infix and answer as a whole are all incorrect.

Comment: @Chowzen lol, I get that. I just meant that since 3 out of the 4 lines fit well, maybe say why the other didn't. Or not. You do you brah

Comment: @PaigeMeinke I've got a killer hint loaded up; trying to decide when to draw and fire.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> [Trombone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trombone)

My prefix takes you down.

> Trom is a common word for weed which takes you high and then DOWN.

My suffix picks you up.

> Bone helps you to pick up

My infix Lets you be,

> B, also can be read as be.

So shut up and kiss me.

> Shut up and kiss the mouth piece and blow it hard.

Comment: interesting! Until now, I was unaware of [the term you have for the prefix](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=trom). Consequently, I did not use it. As with the [other guess I've received,](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63548?noredirect=1) none of the other terms are right.