# My prefix comes before dessert, my postfix really hurts

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

Thought I'd try my hand at a [Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude?noredirect=1&lq=1):

> My prefix comes before dessert.
> My postfix really hurts.
> My infix smells.
> I’m older than the hills.

**What am I?** (8 letters)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Dinosaur

My prefix comes before dessert.

> Din- sounds like *Dine*

My postfix really hurts.

> Saur sounds like *Sore*

My infix smells.

> Nos sounds like *Nose*

Putting them together

> *Dine-Nose-Sore* is pronounced like Dinosaur

I’m older than the hills.

> Dinosaurs first appeared around 240 million years ago

Comment: Bingo!  I was concerned that I was a little too loosey-goosey with the correlations between clues and answer.  I was getting ready to add a hint when you answered