# Magic yet to end

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

Another [Rileyism](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude):

> My prefix is a day,
>   My suffix makes you sway.
>   My infix is a fin,
>   I’m magic yet to end.

What am I?

Comment: We'll need to have a tag for it !

Comment: @Fabich I already asked that on [meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/do-prefix-suffix-infix-riddles-deserve-their-own-tag?cb=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it:

> **Friendship** ?

My prefix is a day,

> **Fri** as in Friday

My suffix makes you sway.

> **Ship** sways I guess...

My infix is a fin,

> Fin = **End**

I’m magic yet to end.

> **Friendship** is a magic yet to end...

Comment: I was referring to the MLP series of that which hasn't ended yet....but yes, nice work!

Answer (score 6):

I believe it is:

> Morrowind

Prefix is a day:

> Morrow, short for tomorrow

Suffix makes you sway:

> Wind

Infix is a fin:

> Row, or maybe rowin(g), since in rowing you use oars as fins.

Magic yet to end:

> This one I don't know, since I've never played the game. I'm guessing it has something to do with the story line. I only know that magic exists in the elder scrolls games.

Comment: Nope, nver heard of that word! But looking it up, it's a game released in 2002, so I think it's magic has ended. Wind would have to be blowing pretty hard to make me sway, creative answer though! +1