# My prefix can sting, my time is coming

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix can sting
>
> My suffix, anything
>
> My infix is king
>
> My time is coming

<sup>(or "My suffix *is* anything" - but that doesn't scan so well...)</sup>

Many thanks to [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) for this puzzle format.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

(Pardon the formatting, still new to the spoiler tags...)

> Brexit?  
>  B → bee 
>  
>  Rex → king 
>  
>  It → anything 
>  coming soon...

Comment: Thanks M Oehm....still not sure why your '>!' hid the text and my earlier ones didn't, but hopefully I can figure it out before next time...

Comment: Spoiler markup is somewhat tricky. The `>!` must form one huge block and they cannot be followed by another spolier block. You cannot format paragraphs with blank lines in between, but you can introduce explicit line breaks with two or more spaces at the end of a line or with the `<br />` tag.

Comment: @MOehm - is there a meta question about formatting spoiler tags... if not maybe would be helpful...

Comment: Well done good job - didn't see exactly when you posted, but looks like it didn't take you long to figure it out :-)

Comment: @MOehm opened a metaquestion about this... https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6294/how-to-write-an-answer-and-hide-key-clues-and-information-using-the-spoiler-f