# My prefix is a car, my infix is a band, my suffix is a degree

Tags: riddle

Asking a [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/43256) Riddle to pass the time:

> My prefix is a car,
>
> My infix is a band,
>
> My suffix is a degree.
>
> I live on the ground.

**What am I?**

*Note: "I live on the ground" means that I **actually live on the ground.** And all of my type lives on the ground.*

Hint #1:

> I live.

Comment: wouldn't "I live on the land" a bit more.... rhymey? (just a thought)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Inspired by [LorentzB](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/47937/lorentzb) answer

> Cabbage

My prefix is a car

> Cab

My infix is a band

> Abba

My suffix is a degree

> Bage "bachelor of agricultural engineering"

I live on the ground

> Obvious

Comment: Correct answer! But I meant the suffix to be "Bage" as in "bachelor of agricultural engineering" which has to do with the cabbage plant itself. Fix it and you get the tick!

Answer (score 11):

=) I think I (might have) got it this time:

> cabomba. However, ain't they mostly aquatic?

The prefix is:

> CAB

The infix is

> B.o.M

The suffix is:

> MBA

<s>Not sure whether this is the right answer, but here it goes:</s>

> <s>vanadiums</s>

Comment: Oof So close! But the fact that cabomba's are aquatic doesn't really fit the riddle. You'll realize once you see the correct answer :D +1 for the nice answer! The answer does, in fact, live *100%* on the ground.