# A Musical Riley

Tags: riddle, word

Inspired by the original [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude):

> My prefix is used on the lake
>
> My infix, an adventurer can take
>
> My suffix was worshipped by ancient hearts
>
> My whole is made of many parts

Comment: First riddle; took me a while to get the rhymes to work out!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about

> Orchestra? This fits the musical clue in the title.

My prefix is used on a lake:

> “Or”: An oar is used to row a boat. Or is a homophone.

My infix, an adventurer can take:

> Chest - an adventurer could find a treasure chest.

My suffix was worshiped by ancient hearts:

> Ra: the Egyptian sun god.

My whole is made of many parts:

> An orchestra is comprised of multiple parts for different instruments.

Comment: That's it! Nice work!