# An overlapping Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

My attempt at a [Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude):

> My prefix is a limit.
>
> My suffix is quite unlit.
>
> My infix shows what's done--
>
> but I'm afraid I don't have one.

What am I?

Comment: This is my first puzzle, so if anyone has any suggestions please let me know!

Comment: Could you please add a hint?? Is it an everyday object or something which we have to bury our heads in Google to know the word? Is it a common word or a proper noun?? Thank you! :)

Comment: @KarisYuen It is a word most people should know (not a proper noun), but isn't in particularly common use. It is a noun, but an idea rather than an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it -

> Infinite

Prefix-

> Inf , which mins infimum,in math, infimum of a set is its greatest lower bound.

Suffix-

> nite, as in night, is quite unlit.

Infix-

> fini, it means the end, or final state, or finished, which shows what has been done.

Comment: Yep, that's it!

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Maxwell

My prefix is a limit.

> Max

My suffix is quite unlit.

> Well

My infix shows what's done--

> ?

but I'm afraid I don't have one.

> Maxwell is a coffee brand

Comment: That's an interesting answer! Unfortunately, as it doesn't fit the infix clue, it's not correct.