# But...you like snacks

Tags: riddle

> I have snacks that you want.
>
> You are not sure you want to eat my snacks.
>
> I am hiding in the darkness.
>
> You stand on the lawn, looking at the blue sky.
>
> Your feet are so close to my throat.
>
> I will swallow your frightened, shivering body.
>
> You will feed me your children before I eat you.

**What is my name?**

> this question has been put on hold so I want to give the answer.

I am a:

> Bomb Shelter

I have the snacks you want.

> Bomb shelters are well stocked with food for the "end of the world".

You are not sure you want to eat these snacks

> You don't want the "end of the world".

I am hiding in the darkness.

> Bomb shelters are usually underground.

You stand on the lawn, looking at the blue sky.

> You are watching the sky for the incoming missiles.

Your feet are so close to my throat.

> Bomb shelters are usually buried in the back yard. The entrance hatch to the bomb shelter is right there peaking out of ground of your lawn.

I will swallow your frightened, shivering body.

> When you need to use your bomb shelter it will be for a terrifying event.

You will feed my your children before I eat you.

> "Women and children first"

Comment: I read the first line and I was like...Darth Vader?

Answer (score 9):

Might you be the [famous](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/36023)

> **Hammock**?

I have snacks that you want.
You are not sure you want to eat my snacks.

> Mock ham

I am hiding in the darkness.

> Hanging in the shade of the trees it's attached to

You stand on the lawn, looking at the blue sky.

> Hammocks are typically used on sunny days only, and you'd hang them outdoors, maybe in the back yard where you have a lawn

Your feet are so close to my throat.

> When you lie down on a hammock, your feet are close to the narrow bit where the strings attach to the rope

I will swallow your frightened, shivering body.

> Getting into a hammock is a pretty jittery thing: without the right technique, you get scared of falling at least once or twice before you get in.

You will feed me your children before I eat you.

> Wouldn't recommend getting many people in the same hammock, but if you really wanted to, that's how you would need to do it. (Also, the kids might have their own hammocks, which, as noted earlier, are quite tricky to get into, so the kids are going to need help.)

Comment: That is not the answer I am looking for, but jeez, that is probably a better answer than the one I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Are you..

> The Puff Adder snake

I have snacks that you want.

> A Puff adder snake, lures frogs in with its tongue, resembling a snack for frogs

You are not sure you want to eat my snacks.

> It usually doesn't end well for frogs, and they are timid by nature

I am hiding in the darkness.

> The puff adder always uses stealth, when it is hunting/luring

You stand on the lawn, looking at the blue sky.

> Frogs eyes are on the top of their head.

Your feet are so close to my throat.

> if the lure to work, the frog gets really close to the snakes mouth.

I will swallow your frightened, shivering body.

> Snakes swallow their food whole. but since it is extremly venomous, it probably dies quickly.

You will feed me your children before I eat you.

> Older frogs, with more experience, will be more hesitant to take the bait.

Comment: It seems that your answer certainly fits. However, that is not the answer I am looking for. In this riddle, the 'you' refers to a person. I don't know enough about you to know if you are one of these people, but this is a kind of person that I think everyone is familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. Honestly, this is probably not the right answer, but is it a

> Mushroom?

I have snacks that you want. You are not sure you want to eat my snacks.

> Mushroom snacks?

I am hiding in the darkness

> Mushrooms are kind of short and they hide in shadows of trees and stuff

You stand on the lawn, looking at the blue sky. Your feet are so close to my throat.

> When you stand next to the mushroom, your feet are pretty close to its throat/stalk.

I will swallow your frightened, shivering body.

> When you die and decompose, mushrooms take in your nutrients b/c they are decomposers.

You will feed me your children before I eat you.

> Not sure about this :P

Comment: Please don't tell me this is right..

Comment: Your second thing made me lol

Comment: I am tempted to edit out the last line of the riddle so that 'mushrooms' could be the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you...

> A mosquito?

I have snacks that you want.

> Mosquitos snack on blood, which is something you might want for research, transfusions, dinosaurs, etc.

You are not sure you want to eat my snacks.

> You’re probably not a fan of eating blood from a mosquito, for reasons that I hope are obvious.

I am hiding in the darkness.

> Mosquitos often come out at night.

You stand on the lawn, looking at the blue sky.

> Mosquitos watch us from afar, and attack us when we are distracted by nature.

Your feet are so close to my throat.

> I am barefoot on the lawn, so that is probably where the mosquitos will land.

I will swallow your frightened, shivering body.

> This is what gave the riddle away. This is a mosquito bite.

You will feed me your children before I eat you.

> OK, but it’s not my fault. Children are just easier targets for mosquitos.

Comment: That is a fantastic answer. I was just thinking about what kind of a hint I could give and I was thinking "it is something usually associated with small towns or other rural living, not cities", but your answer would still fit just fine. (it's not the answer I am looking for though)

Answer (score 2):

(I've never read the story in english but in Dutch, that's why I'm using [this website as a source](https://www.grimmstories.com/language.php?grimm=015&l=en&r=nl).)

Are you:

> the witch from the fairy tale Hansel and Gretel

I have snacks that you want.

> ...they saw that the house was built of bread, and roofed with cakes; and the window was of transparent sugar. "We will have some of this," said Hansel, "and make a fine meal.

You are not sure you want to eat my snacks.

> It's a house in the middle of the forest.

I am hiding in the darkness.

> It's a witch that lives in a forest

You stand on the lawn, looking at the blue sky.

> In the lawn of the house they could look up to the sky I guess

Your feet are so close to my throat.

> She's about to eat the kids?

I will swallow your frightened, shivering body.

> ... she said to herself, "What a fine feast I shall have!" ... And when he is fat enough I will eat him."

You will feed me your children before I eat you.

> She'll eat his testicles too I suppose?

Comment: I think you are on the right track, but in that story you are supposed to see the house and snacks, and in that forrest I don't know that you would really be able to get a good look at the sky.

Comment: Now is my mind going trough all of my childhood fairy tales :s

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean it like that...

Answer (score 1):

Your name is

> Erik, and you are talking about your hen (or other fowl) you are growing

I have snacks that you want.

> You feed her

You are not sure you want to eat my snacks.

> Hens are usually a bit afraid of us big people, but eat eagerly when thrown some food

I am hiding in the darkness.

> If you want to catch a hen, it's better to sneak on her

You stand on the lawn, looking at the blue sky.

> Typical for a free roaming hen

Your feet are so close to my throat.

> A bit silly, but when you eat the hen, you discard the feet (but munch on the legs)

I will swallow your frightened, shivering body.

> The gruesome fate of domesticated fowl...

You will feed me your children before I eat you.

> During her life, you took and ate a lot of her eggs. Then, when she's getting older, you kill and eat her.

Comment: I think that for that to be the right answer I would need to either be a vegetarian or I would have to REALLY love eating meat. I think your answer has made me want to go easy on the meat for a while.

Answer (score 1):

The answer might be:

> Earth

I have snacks that you want.

> Depends, either snacks refer to actual food, like growing stuff from the earth. Or it refers to minerals, oil, etc.

You are not sure you want to eat my snacks.

> If it refers to stuff like oil, you would probably want it, yet you don't want to "eat/use/consume" it because of pollution. Or you simply don't want to eat everything from the ground/earth.

I am hiding in the darkness.

> Earth is below ground, so it is dark.

Alt:

> If not talking about earth as in dirt but earth as in planet. It's in space, a vast darkness. (Except for sun/starlight) It's often depicted as black though.

You stand on the lawn, looking at the blue sky.

Your feet are so close to my throat.

> These two are read as one. When you stand on the ground you are standing on earth. So... pretty close to the "throat". Another thing would be, since we cause pollution and use natural resources we are at the earth's throat, threatening to do more lasting damage/ killing it.

I will swallow your frightened, shivering body.

> We bury our dead. Well we don't do that while they live (mostly) but I'd be frightened and shivering if I was buried alive....so...yeah.

You will feed me your children before I eat you. 
 Again multiple ideas how to read it.

> Either we feed it (the resources) into our children. Then we die and it swallows us.

Or

> We "feed" our children by birthing them to the earth. Then we die and it swallows us.

Or

> We use up everything the earth offers us to our children and then we die out, because it becomes a barren wasteland swallowing us whole.

Comment: Earth is below ground???

Comment: Well earth as in dirt. Don't you use that word in English in that way too? In German Earth is the planet name es well as ... well the brown stuff the outer crust is made of and plants grow in. That's below the ground isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I was not sure what to do if I had two ideas for an answer. So I posted two, so in case one is correct it is possible to distinguish.

Another thing I just thought of

> Emotion

I have snacks that you want.

> You crave for happiness and good emotions. Sometimes even sad ones. You might enjoy sad movies for example.

You are not sure you want to eat my snacks.

> You don't want sadness, anger, etc. So endulging in such emotions might not be wanted.

I am hiding in the darkness.

> Emotions are hiding in subconciousness, can not be seen, often not controlled.

You stand on the lawn, looking at the blue sky.

> This sets up a clear state of mind. Clear sky. Calm. Meditation maybe?

Your feet are so close to my throat.

> In this clear state you are in control of your emotions. So you could for example vanquish anger and leave emotions behind. Being at peace.

I will swallow your frightened, shivering body.

> When frightened you loose control, scream, run, shiver...

You will feed me your children before I eat you. 
 Again multiple ideas how to read it.

> You emotions are fed to your children by your very own acting. If you are always angry your children might suffer from this. If you are always happy they likely benefit from that, etc.

Comment: Both of your answers are way deeper than the answer I am looking for. I am looking for something that is a specific kind of object.

Comment: I just realized that what I said isn't entirely true.  There are different versions, not all of them would be considered 'objects'. (the stereotypical cartoon representation is a kind of object)

Comment: Then I'll see if I can think a little more shallow from now on. ;)