# I'm no Riley! Honest!

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

[I thought of this riddle myself. Feedback is appreciated.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/18349)

> My prefix is meta.
>
> My suffix is better.
>
> My infix holds the key.
>
> I lie, as you can see.

**What am I?**

Comment: ROT13: Jbhyq gur gnt "yvnef" or nccebcevngr urer? KQ

Comment: @NL628 reading the tag description for the one you suggest, I don't think it fits here...

Answer (score 17):

I think this riddle is:

> Untrustworthy.

My prefix is meta:

> "Un" is a real prefix, unlike many Riley riddles where the prefix is a word e.g. "ham" in the original riddle.

My suffix is better:

> Or in other words, "worthy".

My infix holds the key:

> Like assets held in a "trust"

The title claims that this is "no Riley! Honest!"

> But it lies, because it is untrustworthy.

Also:

> “I thought of this riddle myself” links to Riley’s riddle, another untruth.

Comment: This is along the right lines, but not the answer I was expecting. It would likely be "worthier" if it were, since "good" would be "worthy".

Comment: +1 because you have a good answer and because your rep is 666...

Comment: I actually like this better than the intended answer.

Answer (score 3):

*My prefix is meta.*

> **dis** is a real prefix (similar to @anything’s post) used to mean the opposite of what it’s a prefix of. It also means to insult (a variant spelling of diss).

*My suffix is better.*

> Being **honest** yourself is better than dissing others.

*My infix holds the key.*

> Only **one** can be the key

*I lie, as you can see.*

> The puzzle is a classic Riley riddle; the title is a lie. Hence, you are the opposite of what you claim; you are **dishonest**.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've forgotten the intended answer to this riddle. I don't think your clue 3 is right, though, but the solution seems along the right lines.

Comment: A laptop failure took out my answer sheet, and my backup copy isn't readily accessible. In theory I have access to the information, and at some point could come back and declare a winner, but right now I cannot. (Also, both the aforementioned statement and this current one are lies, to ensure that this comment cannot be interpreted as part of a puzzle.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Does rot13(hagehgushy be hansvgushy) ring a bell?

Comment: No, but gur gvgyr orvat n pyhr does.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Is it rot13(habevtvany)?

Comment: I don't see how it could be.

Answer (score 0):

New Answer

> **SELF-RIGHTEOUS**

My prefix is meta.

> **SELF** - META?

My suffix is better.

> **RIGHTEOUS** - morally right, better than bad

My infix holds the key.

> **RIGHT** - Being Self-righteous means always thinking you're right. Or being right may be the key to getting this answer right?

I lie, as you can see.

> Someone who is self-righteous may lie to feel better about themselves

Previous answer

> DENIGRATE :( wrong answer...

Comment: This is incorrect.