# I smell good, but kill

Tags: riddle

> I smell good, but kill.
>
> I provides safety, when danger is near.
>
> Eat me, and die.
>
> The chemicals inside me are nigh.

**What am I?**

Comment: Almost anything (like "house", "horse", "poison", "OJ Simpson", "pinecone", "bottle", "pants", ... ) could fit these clues with a little explanation effort. Please consider adding some means to better identify the intended answer. A wordplay clue ([or three](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/36023)) has been deemed an excellent way to make the answer unique.

Comment: Is it a who or a what am I?

Comment: @Bass OJ Simpson...hmmm :P

Answer (score 4):

> This fits Ethylene Glycol, which is used in antifreeze. It is [sweet smelling and toxic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylene_glycol_poisoning), and has therefore even been [used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacey_Castor) as a [murder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynn_Turner_(murderer)) weapon. It reduces the freezing point and is used as a de-icer, so it provides safety when temperatures are near freezing. Carbon(6) and Oxygen(8), which are in this compund, are close to each other in the periodic table.