# Ughhh! Another?

Tags: word, humor

Or course copying [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) awesome, original by Riley, here is one of my own.

> My prefix is a strap/loop (or a group)
>   My first infix is additional
>   My second infix can mean happiness
>   My suffix is a cart
>   This is what I am joining

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The bandwagon

strap/loop or group

> band

additional

> and

happiness

> uhh, wag like how dogs wag their tails?

cart

> wagon

This is what you're joining

> several Riley style riddles :p

Comment: ninjad by hex rip me

Comment: Wow that was fast. I though I made it tricky this time ^-^. Good job, you will get a check soon since you posted before Hexomino

Comment: +1 I think you beat me by 3 seconds.