# I reroll a needy third

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix I trail,
> My suffix is male,
> My infix is home to a wonder.
> I make my prefix periodic,
> My infix melodic,
> My suffix detrimentally blunder.

**What am I?**

*<sup>Inspired by the original ['Riley riddle'](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/48337).</sup>*

Comment: Another Riley??? :P Ok ok

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are and the word is

> **anagram**

My prefix I trail,

> I'm at the loss for this first one.
>  But maybe the full answer to "What am I" is meant to be "an anagram", where the prefix *an* would reappear as the indefinite article, with you (anagram) trailing it.

My suffix is male,

> just *m*, short for male in many forms querying the sex of a person
>  hagfy suggested *ram* instead, which is a better fit and makes more sense in the second part of the answer, but it overlaps with the infix, so I'll leave both options in.

My infix is home to a wonder.

> *Agra* is home to the Taj Mahal, one of the so-called modern seven wonders of the world.

Now here is the twist for the remaining three

> With the phrasing *I make* and you being anagram, I suppose the next three hints refer to anagrams of the prefix, infix and suffix respectively.

I make my prefix periodic

> The anagram of *an* is *na*, which stands for sodium in the periodic table of elements

My infix melodic,

> one possible anagram to *Agra* would be *Raga*, a musical style. Or, more precisely: "the melodic framework for improvisation akin to a melodic mode in Indian classical music" (quoting Wikipedia)

My suffix detrimentally blunder.

> I suppose this refers to the fact that there is no anagram to a single letter.
>  With hagfy's suggestion instead, this would be *mar*, which fits nicely.

The title, as Mister B keenly spotted and NL628 already indicated right away

> is an anagram of "another riley riddle".

Thanks to Mister B and hagfy for helping with the details.

Comment: I like your answer.  I was thinking the suffix could be the last three letters [rot13(znyr furrc)] and the blunder could be rot13(zne)?

Comment: Also rot13: gvgyr vf nantenz bs "nabgure evyrl evqqyr"

Comment: @hagfy: Good idea, and linguistically I like that better than my suggestion. However, that would mean that infix and suffix would overlap, while prefix and infix wouldn't, which I don't like from an aesthetic point of view, because I think that for those kind of riddles, the pieces should match rather exactly, than arbitrarily. Let's see what noedne has to say.

Comment: @Mister B: Oh, very well spotted. Thanks for the hint. I'll include that in the answer.

Comment: Excellent work! Hagfy is correct, but I see your point about the asymmetry of the wordplay (something to keep in mind for the future). The prefix does refer to the phrase you mention; although that is not the answer, it is a common usage of the answer word.

Comment: @noedne: Thanks for the fast feedback and the kind words. - I totally don't get that hint, however. Trailing this prefix is a common usage of the answer word?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I meant that you correctly reasoned that "nantenz" trails "na" because of the phrase "na nantenz."

Comment: @noedne: OK. But than you said that it's not the answer. If my reasoning is correct, what's left to not being the answer? - But since we don't want to hint at too much in the comments, just let me think about that for a little while. Maybe I'll get it.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that "nantenz" is the answer as opposed to "na nantenz."