# Riley Riley Riley

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

My prefix may be any of various Rileys.
My infix is Riley's.
Most Riley riddles don't do my suffix,
but Riley riddles do my whole.
What am I?

Hint added later:

> "My prefix may be any of various Rileys" — like Riley B. King, Dorothy Comstock Riley, or Jack Riley.

Hint added even later:

> "My infix is Riley's" — could've been written "My infix may be of Riley", instead, had I wanted to make this riddle a little easier.

Comment: Is this a [tag:metapuzzle]?

Comment: You’re a Riley, obviously.

Comment: @CG. the page you linked to has no explanation, so I don't know what you mean.

Comment: CG meant [tag:metapuzzles]

Comment: @Rubio ah, then no.

Comment: rot13("Zbfg Evyrl evqqyrf qba'g qb zl fhssvk", znxrf zr guvax bs yvrf be yvmr(cbffvoyl ylvat). Evyrl Evqqyrf gryy gur gehgu naq qb abg zvfvasbez be "gryy yvrf", ohg pna'g frrz gb svg gur cersvk be vasvk jvgu yvrf/yvmr. Nz v ba gur evtug genpx be fubhyq v ybbx sbe nabgure fhssvk?

Comment: @Prim3numbah, the latter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> Proliferate (thanks msh210 for clarifying).

My prefix may be any of various Rileys.

> **Pro** = short for professional, the people you mention in the hint are all professionals.

My infix is Riley's.

> **Life**, as in "Life of Riley" suggested in Hint 2

Most Riley riddles don't do my suffix,

> **Rate**, most people don't rate them as puzzles
>  **NB:** Clarified by msh210, originally I had **ration**

but Riley riddles do my whole.

> **Proliferate**, yes, there are loads of them.

Comment: Close enough, and I'll give you the checkmark, but I actually intended that most don't rate.

Comment: @msh210 Ah, you know what, I originally thought that and then talked myself out of it. I will edit and clarify, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Are you

> WORDPLAY?

*My prefix may be any of various Rileys.*

> The answer to nearly every "Riley riddle" is a WORD.

*My infix is Riley's.*

> I'm not sure what is the intended infix here. Maybe DP stands for something?

*Most Riley riddles don't do my suffix,*

> They don't PLAY, but ...

*but Riley riddles do my whole.*

> The "Riley riddles" involve WORDPLAY and are often tagged as such.

*What am I?*

> [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay)

Comment: Not the intended solution, sorry. It's not that Riley riddles do wordplay (they _are_ wordplay), you haven't really explained how Rileys _are_ words, and you don't have the infix.

Comment: You may want to see the hint I've added to the question.

Comment: You may want to see the second hint I've added to the question.