# Condensed and Riled up riddle

Tags: riddle

> It tolls, for the sovereign who does not own.
>
> His subjects are calling for his head or his throne.

**What are they?**

Hint:

> Maybe this was more enigmatic than I envisioned, so here's a first hint:
>
> The title is important for figuring out how to approach the riddle.

Hint:

> My prefix strikes a chord
>  My infix is a (misspelt) lord
>  My suffix has a lease
>  I describe countries not at peace.

Comment: First riddle - got too excited and didn't check :)

Comment: It's a good practice to wait one day for giving hint, as not everyone is on the same time zone. United States is steel sleeping for example. The same thing can be applied to accept answer (even if here, the acepted one is usually the first correct answer), so everyone have a minimum amount of time to answer your question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What are they? They are:

> **BELLIGERENTS**
>
>  Countries at war are described as belligerents

It tolls
My prefix strikes a chord

> Bells toll
>  Bells are also a musical instrument

My infix is a (misspelt) lord

> A liege is a lord, "lige" is a misspelling of the same

My suffix has a lease

> a.k.a. Rent

Condensed and Riled up riddle

> Riled up, since it has a Riley-style hint, plus the original question also appeared to be working towards a Riley-style approach
>  Condensed due to the intentional dropping of letters to form the final result

Comment: Correct, well done

Comment: Thank you too, and a nice riddle. It was tricky until you added the hints  @anything

Answer (score 3):

Is it a

> Chairman (of a company board)?

It tolls, for the sovereign who does not own.

> The chairman does not own the company while having supreme rank, power, or authority, and it tolls because..

His subjects are calling for his head or his throne.

> ..people call for his "head" or his "throne" when things go bad, plus they are literally calling for his head (the man) and his throne (the chair)

Also it is a "Condensed and Riled up riddle"

> Since the word chairman consists of the "prefix" chair, the "suffix" man and the answer to the riddle is its "whole", which constitutes [a condensed version of an original Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/47227)

Comment: (+1) for a great answer although not the one I intended. Your interpretation of the title is correct, but there are clues in the riddle to match each *fix separately

Comment: Nice interpretation of head & throne, @onlyf