# What country am I? A 'Riley Riddle'

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, geography, affix-riddle

> My prefix can be seen in the Greek alphabet,
>
> My suffix is a kind of tree,
>
> And my infix is something used to kiss.

**What country am I?**

Comment: An affix is a part of a word that adds meaning to the base word. It's just not any sequence of letters within a word.

Comment: @Richard That's based on the recent trend to copy my [puzzle format](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/41566). Regardless, riddles don't have to be literal.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it is

> Your home country, **Philippines**, :)

As

> My prefix can be seen in the Greek alphabet: **PHI**
>  My suffix is a kind of tree: **PINES**
>  And my infix is something used to kiss: **LIP**

Comment: wow, thanks for answering this is my first post here haha thanks

Comment: 17 seconds. Damn it. :)

Answer (score 21):

The answer is

> PHILIPPINES

Prefix:

> Phi-Letter in Greek alphabet.

Suffix:

> Pines are a kind of tree.

Infix:

> Lip is used to kiss something/someone.

Comment: 17 seconds. Ouch!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is-

> Philippines

prefix:

> Phi is a Greek letter

infix:

> lip is needed to kiss

suffix:

> pines or pine is a kind of tree.

P.S. didn't see the accepted answer yet, but might be same.