# Riley from YouTube

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle, affix-riddle

Maybe a little late, but I think now is the right time. Inspired by the original [Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude):

> My [Suffix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZONpNkABnk),
>
> My [Infix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9s_FpMpdYW8),
>
> My [Prefix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7n1r5XfVkyk),
>
> It's all from YouTube, not from Netflix.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is that you're

> an Avenger.

Prefix

> The video poster's handle is **AvE**

Infix

> The man in the video is Andrew **Ng**.

Suffix

> The concert is from the **E**motional **R**oadshow tour.

Comment: ah.. I knew it would be easy.. :( btw Emotional Roadshow from Twenty one pilot is also known with #ERS so the answer is "Avengers" ;)