# Another Riley Riddle for all of you

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My prefix is when you don't quite get something
>
> I have two infix and it comes in this order
>
> My first infix pertains to a girl
>
> My second infix can pertain to the flowing of liquid
>
> And my suffix has something to do with a circle
>
> Also, you can find me in the United States

What is my name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> **Mississippi**.

My prefix is when you don't quite get something

> You **miss** it.

My first infix pertains to a girl

> **Sis** is short for *sister*.

My second infix can pertain to the flowing of liquid

> You **sip** liquid.

And my suffix has something to do with a circle

> **Pi** is the ratio of a circle's diameter to its radius.

Also, you can find me in the United States

> **Mississippi** is both a state and a river in the US.

Comment: I don't think repetition of letters in prefix and infix are allowed.

Comment: @Sid I don't know of any official rules for riddles or this type of riddle in particular. 'Fixes are frequently overlapped ([even by Riley himself](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/48337)) and can make for a tidy construction.

Comment: @Sid sorry I do not know the rules of that