# Another Riley puzzle 'My prefix is part of a race.....'

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> My prefix is part of a race,
>
> My suffix likes to wear lace,
>
> My infix wonders and is wistful,
>
> My whole has arrows by the fistful.

Many thanks to [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) for this puzzle format.

Comment: @noedne - thanks for correcting that mistake

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm guessing:

> Legolas

My prefix is part of a race

> leg

My suffix likes to wear lace

> las (lass)

My infix wonders and is wistful

> the *ego*

My whole has arrows by the fistful.

> Legolas is a skillful archer.