# A connection between Riley Riddles and I

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

*The following riddle was inspired by what is referred to as "[Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566/riley) Puzzles / Riddles" ([example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude?noredirect=1&lq=1)).*

---

Another Riley Riddle! This one keeps to the traditions, but it might be a little too hard. I will give out hints every $24$ hours.

> My prefix is a question.
>
> My suffix, mean but golden.
>
> My infix has two heads,
>
> But I have bars instead.

What am I?

The answer has $4$ letters, and the title is a clue.

---

*Other inspirations include [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62726/tired-of-me-yet?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this one, too](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64950/another-riley-puzzle-my-prefix-is-part-of-a-race?rq=1).*

Comment: All the capitalized letters in the title make out to be arri, a motion picture company

Comment: @Duck That was just a pure coincidence (...or was it not, subconsciously?), but it would be even better if you could relate that to the actual answer :)

Comment: Oh, I thought I got on something there, lol :)

Comment: Hmm I feel like the suffix here is -au, but the only words that end in au is prau, luau, beau, and unau

Comment: @North when I say what my affixes are, think **vocally**; (ROT13) gur fhssvk vf abg "nh" :)

Comment: The suffix is mean but golden; the golden mean? Arri the company, take out one r and it becomes the first three letters of Aristotle, the person who started this idea

Comment: @Duck (ROT13) lbh tbg gur fhssvk! Nevfgbgyr'f 'tbyqra zrna' (12 iveghrf) vf whfg n syhxr! Jbj!!

Comment: rot13 Fb gur fhssvk vf nev?

Comment: @Duck (ROT13) Ab, gur fhssvk vf gur tbyqra zrna, be ng yrnfg, fbhaqf yvxr vg :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are

> wifi.

```
My prefix is a question.
```

> "Why?"

```
My suffix, mean but golden.
```

> Phi.

```
My infix has two heads,
```

> "if". Not sure exactly why "two heads", though. Perhaps they refer to the antecedent and consequent. Perhaps they're the two letters. Perhaps something I haven't thought of. [EDITED to add:] OP explains in comments that this is a reference to the $\Leftrightarrow$ symbol for "iff", though personally I pronounce that "if and only if" which isn't exactly the infix here :-).

```
But I have bars instead.
```

> Used to indicate strength of wifi signal.

The title ("A connection between Riley Riddles and I")

> is presumably punning on the word *connection*: OP reads and posts Riley riddles over wifi.

Comment: rot13 Jung unccrarq gb gur tbyqra zrna?

Comment: (ROT13) unir lbh urneq bs "vs naq bayl vs"? :)

Comment: @Duck (ROT13) Cuv vf gur tbyqra zrna nf jryy. Zrna = nirentr (be engvb, va guvf cnegvphyne pbagrkg, V fhccbfr).

Comment: Oh, I see, I just thought that it would be more philosophical.

Comment: @user477343 Yes, I have, but I don't understand what relevance it has here: it's not what appears in the word (one "f" too few) and I'm not sure in what sense it has "two heads" anyway. (More like two tails, no?)

Comment: $\iff$ is an arrow with...

Comment: Oh, I see. It feels a bit strange to say "X has two heads" when the actual situation is that X has one head while *something else that sounds like X* differs from X by having two heads instead of one. But no matter :-).

Comment: Well, I wanted it to be short and sweet and also rhyming, so I only had few words to work with. Sorry if it sounded quite vague, but (ROT13) pbatenghyngvbaf ba trggvat gur nafjre pbeerpg! V jvyy npprcg vg naq tvir lbh n gvpx va 20 ubhef jura V pna hcibgr naq rfpncr zl qnvyl ibgvat yvzvg. (Nyfb, vg jvyy tvir fbzr gvzr sbe bgure hfref gb nggrzcg naq fbyivat gur chmmyr naq ubcrshyyl rawbl vg.) :D **Edit:** Oh, and one last thing: you might want to explain the title as well, if you want; though I think it is fairly obvious now :)

Comment: @user477343 Short and sweet and rhyming? Hmm. "Start definitely, end poultry, mid masculinity, thus next we'll see." How's that, then? :-)

Comment: Well, congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$