# A Riley limerick

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle, limerick

A [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude?noredirect=1&lq=1) limerick:

> My prefix is somewhere you’ve been
> My suffix was worshipped back when
> My middle you’ll find
> Is deep in your mind
> Together I show where you’ve been

**What am I?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Camera

My prefix is somewhere you’ve been

> <s>Came</s> 
>  CA is short for California, a common destination.

My suffix was worshipped back when

> Ra - the ancient Egyptian sun god

My middle you’ll find 
Is deep in your mind

> Me

Together I show where you’ve been

> A camera's photos can show you where you've been.

Comment: Dang, that was fast.  That is not quite what I had in mind for the first line.

Comment: Interesting, that was the bit I was most confident about. I have another idea for what the answer should be. Is it to do with time rather than space?

Comment: Think abbreviation.  Not _everyone_ has been there, but it is a common destination.

Comment: @AlanHoover: Seeing the corrected version: That may be a common destination for Americans, but not for most of us in the rest of the world.

Comment: @celtschk fair point.  I took some liberties to fit the structure