# My prefix is a formula, my suffix being shared

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

*The following riddle was inspired by what is referred to as "[Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566/riley) Puzzles / Riddles" ([example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude?noredirect=1&lq=1)).*

---

> *My prefix is a formula, 
>  My suffix being shared. 
>  My infix starts a warm colour, 
>  Though cast away the heat declared. 
>  
>  618 is the number when, 
>  You join my elements; 
>  Find them in a table, then, 
>  My prefix is a consequence.*

**What am I?**

---

**Hint / Bonus Puzzle:**

> *My suffix is the past, 
>  Of what is mostly done to me. 
>  When hot, I will not last; 
>  I must be in a low degree. 
>  
>  As a flavour, I am classed; 
>  Unless there be an allergy.* 
>  Dessert or snacks are of my vast, 
>  A purple wear from _______.

---

*Other inspirations include [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65247/riley-riddle-because-you-know-you-want-to) and [this one, too](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66032/heres-a-clean-riddle?noredirect=1&lq=1).*

Also, I have decided that if you solve for the missing (blank) word in the bonus puzzle, I will award you a $50$ rep bounty (just because I can). However, I will have to wait two days from now to award the bounty (and I think an extra day or two if I first accept the answer).

Comment: just wanna make sure, Desert or Dessert?

Comment: @Sensoray oh Jesus, I mean the latter. Sorry about that. I should know a little better...

Comment: The way I always remembered it was, you want more dessert, that's why there are two s's

Comment: @Joe-You-Know hahah, thanks for the tip. Those things always get me. I still struggle on spelling words like *embarrassment*. (I used autocorrect to spell it just then.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you

> chocolate?

My prefix is a formula,

> CHO (ie. Carbon-Hydrogen-Oxygen, an aldehyde fragment or the elements which compose a carbohydrate)

My suffix being shared.

> ATE (you can share food and eat it; also ATE ends both carbohydrate and chocolate - thanks @user477343!!)

My infix starts a warm colour, 
Though cast away the heat declared.

> COL (start of "WARM COLOUR" without "WARM", ie. start of "COLOUR")

618 is the number when, 
You join my elements; 
Find them in a table, then, 
My prefix is a consequence.

> Refers to the fact that chocolate is a carbohydrate and is made up of carbon (element 6), hydrogen (element 1), and oxygen (element 8) on the periodic table. The prefix, as alluded to before, is the combination C-H-O.

As for the bonus,

> My suffix is the past, 
>  Of what is mostly done to me. 
>  **ATE is the past tense of "EAT", which is what mostly happens to chocolate** 
>  When hot, I will not last; 
>  I must be in a low degree. 
>  **Chocolate melts at high temperatures and so must be kept cool unless you want it melting on your fingers.** 
>  
>  As a flavour, I am classed; 
>  Unless there be an allergy. 
>  **Chocolate is delicious and can come in many forms or classes (ie. milk, dark, white, etc.); but some of the ingredients in chocolate (wheat, nuts, milk) can cause allergies** 
>  Dessert or snacks are of my vast, 
>  **Chocolate is usually found as part of a dessert or snack food** 
>  A purple wear from _______. 
>  **Could this be CADBURY (a chocolatier whose chocolates are wrapped in purple, usually and whose name quasi-rhymes with allergy?)**

Comment: Wow, that was quick. You even got the bonus correct! Was there a line that acted as a dead giveaway, or did you just happen to think in the right mindset? Also, regarding the second line, Rot13(Gur jbeq "pneob-ulqengr" unf gur fnzr fhssvk nf "pubpbyngr" (v.r. *ngr*); gurl **funer** gur fnzr fhssvk. Ohg lbhe rkcynangvba vf whfg nf tbbq.) :D

Comment: Thanks! I think 618 was a big help, then after that the rot13(ybj grzcrengherf znqr vg n ovg zber pyrne, naq gur checyr naq eulzvat Pnqohel jvgu nyyretl tbg zr gur erfg bs gur jnl)! Great puzzle! :D