# One, Two, Three, Four, ..., Five, Six, Seven, Riley!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My first may sometimes hold my all.
>   My last may sometimes strike a ball.
>   Between, may sometimes make a shawl.
>   And people sometimes say we're small.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer to this smashing riddle may be

> potatoes

My first may sometimes hold my all.

> *pot* - of potatoes.

My last may sometimes strike a ball.

> *toes* - to kick a ball.

Between, may sometimes make a shawl.

> *tat* - gunny cloth made from jute.

And people sometimes say we're small.

> *small potatoes* - insignificant or unimportant.

Title - One, Two, Three, Four, …, Five, Six, Seven, Riley!

> This is a rhyme used in counting-out games:
>
>  One potato, two potatoes, three potatoes - four
>  Five potatoes, six potatoes, seven potatoes - more
>  Eight potatoes, nine potatoes, ten potatoes - all

Comment: What about the title?

Comment: From Yukon gold to fingerling, you got it without lingering!

Comment: What does Riley have to do with the rest of the counting rhyme?

Comment: @Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine Riley was the first one to ask a riddle of this type on puzzling. It's now considered a type of puzzle. See [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) question for context

Comment: For the middle part: rot13()"Gng" vf nyfb n ireo zrnavat gb znxr ynpr

Comment: @AlanHoover, aha - your meaning makes a better shawl than mine.

Comment: @AlanHoover Thank you. That’s what I intended.