# Here's A Clean Riddle

Tags: riddle

I kinda like [Riley riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude?noredirect=1&lq=1), so here goes nothing.

> My beginning is a fake.
>   My ending, faeces it means.
>   My middle is a unit of electron flow rates.
>   However, as a whole, I keep you clean.

Please comment on how to improve on it! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, Karis! Congratulations on your first riddle as well! Do take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), and we look forward to your continued participation & contributions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are

> **SHAMPOO**

Explanation:

> SHAM - fake
>  AMP - unit of current (ampere)
>  POO - feces

Comment: Wow that was fast! And it's the correct answer. :)