# The Crappiest Riddle. (Parental advisory: vulgar language)

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My start is bullshit.
>   My end can be literal bullshit.
>   My middle gives volume; even to your bullshit.
>   **I** will give volume! (According to my marketing bullshit.)

Who am I?

Comment: Apologies for the rhyming scheme, unfortunately it was thematically required.

Comment: What a load of crap.

Comment: [Obligatory link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66032/heres-a-clean-riddle/)

Comment: This may be a number two.

Comment: @ontamu ah, looks like someone had the exact same idea before me. Given that you need to actually solve both riddles independently to see that they are at all related (which they admittedly, and to a great degree, are), I'd like to suggest that upvoting Phylyp's comment (and the other riddle) might be a better approach than VTCing. As always, it's of course up to you to decide.

Comment: @Bass I just flagged it for possible duplicate, it is up for other people to vote on it. The flag doesn't mean it will be closed I will indeed upvote your comment as you are making a valid point.

Comment: I didn't report this as a duplicate because to me these are two riddles with a similar approach and the same answer, not a repetition of one another, so I just put in a link. As @Bass also pointed out, I didn't realise the connection upon reading the question, but only upon seeing the answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A clean answer is

> shampoo

My start is bullshit

> sham

My end can be literal bullshit

> poo

My middle gives volume; even to your bullshit

> amp-lifier

I will give volume! (According to my marketing bullshit.)

> shampoo - lends luxurious volume to your luscious locks.