# My prefix is the beginning

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix is the beginning,
>   My suffix is too,
>   My infix is telling,
>   What magic makes you do.

**What am I?**

Hint #1

> The suffix is a different beginning than the first line.

Comment: It's been a while since we've seen a Riley :)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie What do you mean, I'm right here :)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie My thoughts exactly :)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie, can you guess what I'm [calling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68750/the-crappiest-riddle-parental-advisory-vulgar-language) :-)

Comment: Copycats these days

Comment: @Sensoray Some hints maybe?

Comment: You have described the beginning, middle, and end of the word, but you haven't provided a line for the word itself. Unless the last two lines are not meant to be read together, but instead as two disjoint clues?

Comment: Are we the magician in this riddle, or the observer?

Comment: @Cubemaster the observer :)

Comment: @IanMacDonald The last 2 lines are separate clues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Believe

Prefix:

> The very beginning of anything is its existence IE to BE

Suffix:

> The Eve is what happens at the start of something (technically before but whatever)

Infix:

> A lie is very telling of someones character (you also tell a lie)

The whole:

> Magic makes you Believe.

Comment: That's it! Though I was thinking a bet more meta for #1, the beginning of beginning is...  Also was thinking the christian beginning for humanity for line #2, but your reasoning works too :)

Comment: I thought about both of those, but I decided to avoid religion, and I thought the meta was coincidence. I also wanted to also go with rot13(ng svefg gurer jnf abguvat, naq gura tbq fnvq yrg gurer or yvtug) but avoided it for the same reason

Answer (score 4):

Is the word

> **Startled**

My prefix is the beginning,

> **Start** marks the beginning.

My suffix is too,

> **Led** i.e. in the beginning.

My infix is telling,

> Not sure but maybe it tells magic is an **art**.

What magic makes you do.

> Magic usually **startles** you, makes you go wow.

Comment: Another good guess! but I don't think it fits the last clue, what does magic make you do? "your answer" That would fit better with what may magic cause you to be?

Answer (score 3):

Probably not right, but are you a

> Prediction?

My prefix is the beginning,

> Pre, meaning before.

My suffix is too,

> This is where I have problems. Tion, is literally the result of an action.

My infix is telling,

> dict (as in dictate), means to say or direct something.

What magic makes you do.

> People who are magicians make predictions about the future.

Comment: Good idea, I like the thought process for this, but the suffix doesn't quite fit.

Comment: I figured. Well, back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 3):

> precise

My prefix is the beginning,

> I agree with Joe that I think it's "pre": before

My suffix is too,

> "ize", "ise": to become. "trophy": growth.

My infix is telling,

> tell; inform; say; sent; speak; talk; brief; instruct; order; direct; command; bid; text. For precise I saw it as "seeing a telltale clue": C.

What magic makes you do.

> Spells to increase your accuracy are part of games... if you aren't precise in your chants than many games / movies have a punishment: the spell doesn't work and something happens to you.

Comment: Interesting guess :) I don't think this quite fits though. If it was that word, I probably could have worded the riddle differently.

Comment: Thought so- I just went through a fat list of words that started with that prefix, storming up answers based on the words I thought might fit.

Comment: Well to save you the trouble of going through all that again, that's not the prefix ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is

> ABRACADABRA

A Latin word for magic.

And the explanation is

> It starts with and ends with *a* the beginning letter of the alphabet.

Not sure about the infix part, though.

Comment: Doesn't quite fit. That'd be more of a say than a do, and the infix doesn't apply.  Nice thought, but reaching.

Answer (score 2):

## New Answer:

> **AWED**

My prefix is the beginning,

> **A** is the first letter of the alphabet

My suffix is too,

> To be **WED** is the beginning of a marriage

My infix is telling,
What magic makes you do.

> Magic makes you **AWED**

### Previous answer

This definitely isn't it, but it works reasonably well:

> **AUTO**

My prefix is the beginning,

> **A** is the first letter of the alphabet

My suffix is too,

> **TO**

My infix is telling,
What magic makes you do.

> Magic makes you say "Ooo", which sounds like **U**

Comment: The last line describes the whole word itself. But good try!

Comment: The third line is just for the infix!