# Riley Riddles in Reverse

Tags: word, no-computers

In the all-famous [Riley riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/36023), you have to guess one word from clues about its prefix, infix and suffix. Here, instead,

> **You get three words.**
>   You must find **one solution word** that you can attach..
>
> - to the **beginning** of one of the three words, (you have to figure out which one)
> - somewhere in the **middle** of another, and
> - to the **end** of the remaining word,
>
> so that in each case, a new, single word is formed.

All the words here are very random, and some of them are even very rare, but every clue, result, and solution word is going to be strictly [valid in Scrabble](https://scrabblewordfinder.org/check).

1. **ionized - flat - beg**
2. **ole - serenity - re**
3. **cation - bat - ha**
4. **inland - asymptotic - dog**
5. **king - sky - at**

If you get stuck, you can write all the five solution words together, and the result will be yet another random Scrabble-valid word.

---

<sub>*PS. This puzzle format is highly experimental, I'm kind of trying out a vague idea I had about puzzle creation. Any feedback and improvement suggestions will be highly appreciated.*</sub>

Comment: I approve of this idea :) Maybe you could link to the original to provide context.

Comment: interesting puzzle, shame it was solved before i saw it :( post some more sometime :)

Comment: As a piece of advice, it seems that this puzzle is extremely easy to solve with a computer. Perhaps the three provided words could instead be clues.  Like it could be "I am a prefix of ... / I am an infix of ... / I am a suffix of ..."

Comment: @Riley Oh, I forgot the link? Fixed now. I noticed the computer bit too, and even though I detest the [tag:no-computers] tag, for this one I had to include it right from the beginning. The clue idea seems nice, and it would definitely make the puzzle more challenging in an interesting way.

Comment: @Dragonrage, yeah, basically it was solved before *anyone* had seen it. And I mean yes, really. The view count was still in the single digits when the answer was posted. Hopefully that didn't stop you from solving the puzzle yourself though!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

1. ionized - flat - beg

   > **UN**ionized - fla**UN**t - beg**UN**
2. ole - serenity - re

   > **DIP**ole - seren**DIP**ity - re**DIP**
3. cation - bat - ha

   > **LO**cation - b**LO**at - ha**LO**
4. inland - asymptotic - dog

   > **MA**inland - asympto**MA**tic - dog**MA**
5. king - sky - at

   > **TIC**king - s**TIC**ky - at**TIC**

Final answer:

> **UNDIPLOMATIC**

Comment: So that would be, what... 6 minutes and 13 seconds. I don't think I could even type this answer that fast. Nicely done. :-)