# Riley Riddles in Reverse, third helping

Tags: word, no-computers

<sub>[Once](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/66920/36023) [more](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/66971/36023)! For science!</sub>

---

Here's yet another batch of "inverted" [Riley riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/36023). The idea is still exactly the same as before:

> **You get three words.**
>   You must find **one solution word** that you can attach..
>
> - to the **beginning** of one of the three words, (you have to figure out which one)
> - somewhere in the **middle** of another, and
> - to the **end** of the remaining word,
>
> so that in each case, a new, single word is formed.

All the words here are very random, and some of them are even very rare, but every clue, result, and solution word is going to be strictly [valid in Scrabble](https://scrabblewordfinder.org/check).

1. **then - but - ba**
2. **died - deter - can**
3. **tone - sold - men**
4. **more - lard - lit**
5. **is - luring - modes**

I deliberately made this batch more difficult than the ones before, so to compensate, the solution words will form an encouraging sentence.

---

<sub>*PS. There are now [three full sets of these puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22riley+riddles+in+reverse%22), and that's probably going to be the proverbial "it". If you could be so kind as to drop a comment about which ones you liked best, and which ones maybe not, I'd be much obliged. Any other comments and suggestions are of course highly appreciated, too. Thanks, and happy puzzling!*</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. then - but - ba

   > **you**then - bu**you**t - ba**you**
2. died - deter - can

   > **can**died - de**can**ter - can**can**
3. tone - sold - men

   > **ace**tone - sol**ace**d - men**ace**
4. more - lard - lit

   > **any**more - l**any**ard - lit**any**
5. is - luring - modes

   > **test**is - lu**test**ring - modes**test**

Final answer:

> **YOU CAN ACE ANY TEST**

Comment: How do people do these so fast?

Comment: with the pressure that other puzzlesolvers are right on my tail!
i had the linked scrabble dictionary open and after getting **YOU CAN** with some thought, the rest was a bit of trial and error with intuition.

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer:

5. is - luring - modes

> **test**is - lu**test**ring - modes**test**