# What have you done when offered a free ride?

Tags: riddle

To solve this, first complete the [Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude?noredirect=1&lq=1) as a clue to the real question, asked below.

**Clue**:

> My prefix can be pumped or eaten
>   My suffix is a French saint.
>   My infix could be a famous French region,
>   but just in the movies by name.

**Question:**

**What have you already done when you are offered a free ride?**

Hint:

> Isn't it...?

Hint 2:

> The clue doesn't refer to a french word, despite how _____ that is.

Comment: Sigo is a roman-french saint

Comment: The best bet is to try to figure out the other clues to help guide you toward which Saint and/or which region it could be referring to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could the clue be

> ironic?

My prefix can be pumped or eaten

> Iron can be pumped or eaten

My suffix is a French saint.

> Nic, as in Saint-Nicolas

My infix could be a famous French region, 
but just in the movies by name.

> The infix is Ron, because the French region is Burgundy, and this was an Afternoon Delight to solve!

Meaning the answer could be

> It's a free ride when you've already paid, a lyric from Ironic by (Canadian!) Alanis Morissette

Comment: You are correct about the clue and the answer! I'd love for you to get all the clues right, and your answer to the French region part is not what I was looking for - also, while you are correct with the answer, you can get an exact quote if you are a rot13(zhfvp sna)

Comment: I've updated the clues...am I closer with the French region?

Comment: To add to that, rot13(eba) isn't a French region that I know of, but there may be someone famous by that name in the movies as well as the region in question

Comment: Nope, it's rot13(n anzr bs n punenpgre gung V'z ybbxvat sbe! Znlor lbh'er n sna bs Fgrc Oebguref be Rys?)

Comment: Got it! Once I stopped thinking about actors, I actually really liked that movie haha

Comment: The description was absolutely perfect - Well done!