# A Daring Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, poetry

> *My prefix is called out after, 
>  The first that passes forty from ties. 
>  My suffix might be the laughter, 
>  When mother's ghost discerns no cries. 
>  
>  My infix is a way of air, 
>  Releasing a way of strong emotion. 
>  The tin boy experienced my fare, 
>  From cities, to the moon, by desert and ocean.*

**What am I?**

---

It is not $100\%$ a [Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I like to be original. Also, there is a clue in the title, as well as some truth — I mean, this riddle should be harder than the usual difficulty I set for my riddles...

...okay I will give out just one hint: the answer has $9$ letters.

---

I showed my friend this riddle and he said that the riddle was too hard, thus I am going to provide a hint for him so when he is active, he can see it.

**Hint:**

> *My suffix is always honest, 
>  If only you switched the central pair. 
>  My name is told and promised, 
>  If only you riskily travelled somewhere.*

Comment: does the last two line (tin boy...) describe the whole word, or is it about the infix ?

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid the last two lines do not describe the infix — they describe the actual word, itself. Otherwise, I would have said something along the lines of `The tin boy experienced my infix's fare`.

Comment: @PotatoLatte I approved of the edit, but it has been [decided in Puzzling.Meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/do-prefix-suffix-infix-riddles-deserve-their-own-tag) that there shouldn't be a tag for Riley Riddles. I am going to edit back to the original.

Comment: +1 for the amazing riddle @user477343

Comment: @KevinL thank you. I am still working on your riddle. The three word phrase is getting me... :)

Comment: Just added a new hint :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think it is-

> Adventure

prefix-

> Ad, it is what an additional point is called in tennis, when both players were tied with 40 points and one player scores a point to break the deus.

infix-

> vent - it is an opening that allows air to pass, also used as a verb that means releasing strong emotion

suffix-

> not sure , but maybe ture which means partying in norway

the last part refers to-

> adventures of tintin, this is what actually gave me the word. In the stories tintin traveled from cities to cities, through desert and ocean, and even went to moon once.

Comment: ROT13 (V guvax gur "nq" cneg ersref gb na "nq fpber" va graavf. Jura qrhpr vf ng 40, jubrire fpberf gjb cbvagf nurnq unf zber nqinagntr bs jvaavat, gurersber gur fpber vf pnyyrq na 'nq')

Comment: yes, your explanation does fit better, I'll add it to my answer..

Comment: Your answer is correct, and every explanation is correct... except the suffix. I will give a hint: what word is there to describe when you are laughing at somebody crying?

Comment: Okay the suffix explanation is here: (ROT13) Vg vf "vzzngher" gb ynhtu ng fbzrbar jub vf pelvat. Gurersber, vs gurl ner abg pelvat, vg zvtug or dhvgr gur bccbfvgr; v.r., "zngher". Vs abobql vf pelvat, gura zbgure'f tubfg pnaabg qvfprea nal pevrf (nf va, xvyy gur zbgure; xvyy gur zn; trg evq bs "zn" va "zngher" gb trg "gher". Gung vf gur fhssvk. Congratulations! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$